# Change color of inline links in SO?

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks

I'm putting in a request to change the color of links in questions to something more distinctive. I don't know about others, but I find them easy to miss with their customary pale blue mixed in with the anemic (what is it, dark gray?) color of the ordinary, non-link text.

Screen shot of the current look. The first 3 links are visited (the 1st one shows the style when it's hovered over). The next 3 show un-visited links (the 1st one of that group also shows the hover-style). The screenshot is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/456814) (italics in the original (added by users) were removed via Chrome developer tools):

[image: Current link styles]

Maybe everybody else's eyes are better than mine, but I would sure appreciate something more attention-grabbing, say a different color or a heavier font. Maybe just **bold** it?

Would this be hard to do? Might it somehow be problematic?

These are the current styles for the links:

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000; /* black */
  font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #0077cc; /* RGB 0,119,204 */
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:visited {
  color: #4a6b82; /* RGB 74,107,130 */
}
```

Comment: This feature request can be improved by providing screenshots (before and after), as well as suggesting CSS rules for the change (you should be able to figure out the appropriate rules using Chrome or Firefox developer tools).

Comment: Good points, @Cupcake. I would be happy to provide a "before" screenshot as it appears on my Safari browser, but is that really helpful? I expect they look the same on any Safari browser on any Mac. I can't provide an "after" shot I have no knowledge at all of CSS rules, nor of Chrome nor Firefox developer tools. I'm sure other browsers are being used here on different platforms, but I don't have either. And it could be that I'm the only one who has mentioned this issue. I'm sure many others here have younger, sharper eyes than do I. Call it an accessibility thing.

Comment: You're not alone, Tim; I've wondered about asking for it -- thank you for actually asking.  (And I don't have the knowledge needed to do a mock-up, either.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there are plenty of web developers hanging out around Meta, I'm sure someone will come along and do it, eventually. I'll do it myself if I have time later.

Comment: It would seem a simple thing, but I've been lulled into believing other things were simple. However, even though you and I may not have the experience to show what difference the change might make, I'm sure others here do. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, CC! I hope I'm not being a PITA--I just think the readability of the site could be improved by a simple tweak.

Comment: Frankly, I don't care for links that stick out like a sore thumb. With a site like Stack Overflow, that has a lot of inline links in questions and answers, if the colors were more vivid it would just make the text harder to read. You don't go hunting for links to click anyway, you read the text and click the ones that are relevant.

Comment: @CodyGray sez: "you read the text and click the ones that are relevant." True, provided you happen to see them. My point here isn't to make them "stick out like a sore thumb." Surely readability can be enhanced within the bounds of good taste.

Comment: Especially if only a single word like "this" is used for the link, I really have a hard time seeing them. A link consisting of several words is not that bad, but could surely be improved.

Comment: I often find myself makeing links bold or italic or wrapped `in code` to make them stand out a little more. Better styles would be better. Just a slightly more distinctive color or even an underline. Doesn't have to be solid. Dotted is fine. It's not just answers, but especially links in comments on SO are practically unrecognizable.

Comment: @GolezTrol--I think the examples Cupcake posted are a great improvement. I can only guess that the change would be formidable--or maybe the honchos on SO are just satisfied with a weak, watery UI. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some screenshots of some of the changes that you suggested. **Note that I'm not a designer nor a UX expert**. I'm just getting the ball rolling.

### Bold Links

[image: Bold links screenshot]

```css
a {
  /* ... */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

### Purple Visited Links

[image: Purple visited links screenshot]

```css
a {
  /* ... */
  color: #8c00f8; /* RGB 140,0,248 */
}
```

### Link Styles on Meta

For comparison, here are what links look like on Meta. Notice the two at the bottom of the screenshot. The first one has the default no-hover style, and the second one has hover-style (change of color):

[image: Meta links screenshot]

```css
.post-text a {
  color: #000; /* black */
  border-bottom: 1px #000 dotted;
}
.post-text a:hover {
  color: #6c0000; /* RGB 108,0,0 */
  border-bottom: 1px #6c0000 dotted;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I think your screen shots make my case, Cupcake. You've been around here longer than I, and you obviously have skills I don't. What do you think--how difficult would it be to make this change for SO? Is it just a quick global tweak, or a major BB-stacking undertaking? Is there bureaucracy involved? Would there be objections? Hard to believe someone would think such a change would make the site LESS readable or attractive, but who knows? Thanks for the time and effort to do the illustration!

Comment: @TimJones I wouldn't think that these changes would be hard to do, but I'm not a member of the Stack Exchange staff, so I don't know how everything is actually implemented. As for the process of convincing other people that this is something that should be done, that's what Meta Stack Overflow is for, you have to make your case and people can vote on whether they agree with you or not. Or someone from the Stack Exchange staff can come by and unilaterally say **No** `;)`

Comment: Well, I can take no for an answer. However, and I hope I don't step on any toes here, but while I don't really know the demographics on SO, I'm guessing that the preponderance of the membership is under the age of 50. I think it's well known that those of us who are over 50 will have lost some of the visual powers of acquisition that we had when we were younger. Could be this is why the issue hasn't received much attention. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: I like the dotted lines from MSO. You can clearly recognize them as links but they are still not too distracting for my mind.

Comment: I strongly dislike the purple color for visited links.