# Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update of 2014

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, Meta.SO looks a bit different today. Over the years I've gotten a lot of requests to "redesign" Stack Overflow. I've always felt SO's site design had good usability and was very functional. However, I did and do agree, aesthetically, it could use some polish.

Today's new Meta theme release is a preview of what the new SO main site theme will be. As you can see, it still feels like Stack Overflow. Most changes are for typographical consistency, white spacing and layout. **It may take a little getting used to** but hopefully if you give it a few days you'll like it better.

We've also refined the Stack Overflow logo slightly for better kerning and a more relaxed curve on the mark. We've updated site icons to svg (with png fallback) to finally get scalable retina support. I feel this is a better approach than using x2, x3..xN pngs since it's more maintainable.

Underneath the skin, I've been reworking our LESS/CSS structure as well. The newly refactored set up would allow us to fix SE Q&A sites' CSS bugs more efficiently and be a lot more bug free when we launch a new site.

**We want your feedback**. This is still a work in progress. There are going to be styling or CSS bugs, so if you find any please tag them with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) so we can fix them as soon as possible.

Comment: Can we have the ugly meta logo back?

Comment: Is that really _better_ kerning? The space in 'rf' seems too big, and the space in 'low' seems too small.

Comment: OMG change!  I was a little startled when my refresh looked so different.  Initial reaction is that I kind of miss the bolded titles, but having the text a little closer in size/weight does make it easier to read.  Just don't go full on Metro (sorry, Microsoft design language).

Comment: The slight font increase was shocking to me (who likes teensy tiny type) but quite readable.

Comment: Looks great. The contrasting greyscale on meta (the darker graphite look) looks awesome.

Comment: Minor, but the badges are missing a hover effect. Is there supposed to be one?

Comment: @animuson good catch. i'll add the hover back.

Comment: I noticed the questions on S.O. no longer appear with the gold background color. Does this have anything to do with that? It felt weird all day looking at question lists with them all having a white background.

Comment: @TyCobb SO main site's css hasn't been touched. the gold background color is for questions that are tagged with your favorite tags. Make sure you have favorite tags right now.

Comment: @Jin I do. I think it's related to the Unanswered section. It was fine this morning and then they all went white after a refresh at work. My bookmarked page is this: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23+vb.net   I'll just make a question since this change didn't cause this. I have C# as my favorites and VB.NET was not in it so it appeared only white for VB.NET questions.

Comment: So it now lookz like pt.SO? I can't say I love the new design. Older was better.

Comment: Are you guys rebranding to Stackover Flow as well?

Comment: My eyes thank you for the @2x images c:

Comment: Suggestion for site background: http://i.snag.gy/AOKxV.jpg

Comment: No Changes, Just want to say Thanks Jin!!!

Comment: previous logo was better i think..

Comment: The logo feels much more lively, as if the rectangles are actually bouncing out of the stack. I like it!

Comment: I don't like it, but I'm probably spoiled by SO-mocking sites. They all feature a more spaced look like this one, it could make it harder for newbie users to distinguish the real SO from them (yes they can look at the URL bar.. but anyway..)

Comment: Bog standard `Courier` for `code`, yuck. The main site uses Consolas, which is much better.

Comment: The comment text is a bit small-ish. ... But, possibly I finally need glasses, after spending 30 yrs behind a monitor.

Comment: it's so hard to read the comments. Could you increase the text font size?

Comment: Is it just me who's always thought the "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" Font looks really out of place?

Comment: When users upvoted comments the number beside it turned redder the higher it was. Was this feature scrapped?

Comment: @nicael I have a feeling pt.so was a trial before bringing it here.

Comment: Maybe my eyes are tired after a long day at the keyboard, or maybe it's just psychosomatic but... The comment font seems worse, maybe it's a different size or font or the anti-aliasing is different, but it definitely seems less readable.

Comment: I do not like that the previous css styles were gutted and replaced with less functional or non-existent styles. This looks like it was not tested at all.

Comment: Aw, I liked the old logo, with color!  This one seems more bland.

Comment: All I have to say is WOW, SO has one hell of a QA dept.

Comment: Eeeek? \*crawls into corner\*

Comment: @TravisJ For the few minor glitches over lots of CSS... not bad at all. I mean, it's CSS -- the land where nothing is easy.

Comment: Can we have a teensy weeny bit of space af the left margin? As it is, images and text are exactly flush left with the edge of my iPad, no margin at all.

Comment: I second the remark about Courier. It is a typewriter font. Never been seen on an actual computer, only in low-end IT books. Use a monospaced sans serif please.

Comment: I don't like the font changes, but I'll probably get used to them.

Comment: May be the Fonts of Comments are changed or the spacing is decreased. It is uneasy to read comments, compared to earlier style fonts.

Comment: My biggest issue is the many different font sizes on SO in general ... there's just sooooo many ... can these be made more consistent? Generally I go by the rule that headings might be larger but beyond that most text is just text and thus should be the same size (general rule only mind)

Comment: When will it be rolled out on SO?

Comment: Are you going to redesign other Trilogy Sites?

Comment: I like the question/answer's new font styling. Pretty clean and easy to read.

Comment: @Jin Hovering over links doesn't seem to underline them like it does on the main site. Dunno if this is intentional, related to [animuson's post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277216/616460), or some other problem.

Comment: For the love of god, please don't change the logo. I hope this isn't too obscene, but frankly, the new one looks like a limp you-know-what.

Comment: I like it, but the comment whitespace is a bit odd. Single-line comments have a ton of space underneath, but multi-line don't? It seems like either the space for single-line comments could be retained and the dividing lines could go away, or the space should be standardized to the smaller margin.

Comment: what about thinking a way to make SO content less garbage and a way of avoiding lazy users, before re-design? The no-answer-no-upvoted question are growing exponentially. A lot of users believe that people here in SO will do the job for them, without even trying to learn the basic or googling  before making a question.

Comment: The font and styling are pretty terrible, in my opinion.  Whatever it was before was very easily readable and scan-able.  No longer.

Comment: when it'll come to SO

Comment: @TNT , Look carefully at the upvotes of comments.You'll see the red color for questions with high amount of upvotes.(And yeah.I agree.Its's too hard to see it. )

Comment: @CoolGuy I posted the comment at a time when the numbers were not red when the comments had a high number of upvotes, as seen in the screenshot in [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277342/3386144) answer. And yes, the colors could be made a little easier to see. I like the old color levels better (gray > black > dark red > red); these seem kinda random (gray > brown > orange > black).

Comment: I personally liked the sparse use of color on the legacy design. Current greyish approach looks like a blurred mass of text.

Comment: Put "meta" on top of "stack overflow" in the logo, but keep the new font. The Trilogy site meta names have "Meta" before the main site name, as in "Meta Stack Overflow", not "Stack Overflow Meta".

Comment: I'm seeing a thin border around the "bug" and "discussion" tags, but no border around the "design" tag. Why wouldn't they have the same style? Using Google Chrome v39.0.2171.65

Comment: I gone through some past post in meta and i found **Profile redesign** Link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype?lq=1) So this design also included in upcoming release, am i right ?

Comment: Do not like the 'new' logo. The old/existing logo graphic felt like it had a complete 90 degree turn. The 'relaxed curve' in the updated graphic doesn't aim anywhere and looks incomplete. If anything I would make the curve tighter, so that it completes its 90 degree turn.

Comment: [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) design :)

Comment: Can I assume this just went live on SO?

Comment: Tagging multiple people in comments is a nice thing I just noticed, but more of a "feature" than a design change. Were new features announced anywhere?

Comment: Yep, it's on main SO now. It wasn't there [earlier today](https://web.archive.org/web/20150115190927/http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Why did this go live on SO when there were apparently still so many issues (which didn’t get fixed on SO)? Also, can we get a new question to discuss this since this one is old and so overused already? It’s hard to navigate.

Comment: StackOverflow is now SUPER UGLY, seriously why did you guys even do this? You aren't Google, no need to "fix" perfectly good things to make them look worse. Fonts are too thin and small, too much white space, ugly kerning, seriously **please roll this back!**

Comment: I'll let my eyes speak: Pre update they didn't hurt, now they hurt when trying to read through the front page. Yes I am serious and I think it's a big issue.

Comment: The new design is just too bland. The question title fonts are far too thin, and the background color too bland, and makes everything feel meh.

Comment: Love it, especially if you guys update/fix with the issues mentioned in the answers section ;)

Comment: I get a headache and my eyes are aching. The new design is terrible http://www.wenpigsfly.org/ranting.gif

Comment: The new font on the main page is about as legible as TYPING IN ALL CAPS.  The sanserif letters run together, especially when painted in that pale color.

Comment: Another decent website is ruined. Seriously, I can't work out whether today's so-called 'web designers' are colour blind or just plain retarded. You are not in a competition to see who can replace the most content with whitespace, please roll this monstrosity back ASAP.

Comment: How do I get back to the old design?

Comment: I like it!  Was pleasantly surprised by the new colors on SO today.  Well done.

Comment: @BSeven You can't. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283630/is-this-flat-theme-new-or-is-there-an-option-to-change-it-back

Comment: It looks very good, I like it!

Comment: Jin, I don't want to start a new question about this, but have you guys gotten any feedback specifically about the style for visited user links?  Having them (unvisited) bright red and then (visited) gray is kinda weird. Looks really weird for mods (the diamond is always red). Is this an oversight, or desired behavior?  Has anybody noticed and pitched a fit at how kinda weird it is?  You think I should FR removing the a:visited  washed out look?

Comment: @Will yep that's a bug. I'm fixing it soon!

Comment: Please remove the bold font style from default. There is no more difference between "bold" and "normal" text, this make no sense!

Comment: Doubt many will read this comment since it is buried, but I'm voting to close this as "unable to reproduce" because the 2014 design is gone, so even if someone wanted to provide feedback, it is pointless since the design is gone

Comment: This post is not a problem report, it is an ask for feedback. The "not reporducible" close reason is here meaningless, undefined.

Comment: @peterh the key phrase in the close reason is "Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete".  The system changed, feedback is no longer needed.  No reason to keep it open and confuse people looking to provide feedback about an old version of the tool

Comment: @psubsee2003 In my opinion, it is a valid argument only from the moment that the community accepts this change in the customs. Note, on this reason, practically all the posts older as some weeks could be closed and nearly all the posts having an accepted answer could be closed. Closure is not for the questions where new answer is not needed, closure is for the questions where some serious reason to forbidding new answers exists.

Comment: @peterh you are still missing my point.  Because of the recent design change in the site, this question is literally unanswerable anymore because no one can provide feedback about design that is gone.  That is different than a question someone asked and and later doesn't need an answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Anybody could give a feedback using the archive.org, but no one has a reason to talk about obsolete designs. I see no reason to use this close reason for posts for which it was clearly not intended (I.e. which are clearly not unreproducible bug reports).

Comment: I would think an historical lock would be more appropriate here than closure.

Answer (score 325):

I actually really like this.

My only "complaints" are:

1. I can't tell what's a link (I wish you guys would just start underlining them).
2. It looks too close to SO (maybe a *slightly* darker, cozier background?)
3. **Biggest one: There is way too much whitespace between one-line comments:**

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 it makes me think "SO tried to hard to have a nice narrow menu, but just a few comments that fit on one line will add a lot of empty space, seems pretty inconsistent to me!". Next step: add a big banner to the menu! haha

Comment: The space is there to make room for the flag button.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Yeah, but something about the font or something else on the page makes it look really big, I think. I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: The comment font is apparently slightly smaller now, but we might as well make it larger again if we're going to have that much whitespace between comments.

Comment: The Guy with The Hat is right about the flag icon. That could fly off to the left, or overlay the text with a white background... I'd prefer either of those to the extra spaaaaace.

Comment: I have always wanted to see the flag icons be next to the vote icons, but I didn't want to mention it in the post because it's more of a separate feature request than a comment on the design change (the flag / vote icon layout isn't unique to SO meta or part of this change).

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Flags are on the left, not underneath.

Comment: @TylerH They _are_ to the left, but they are _also_ lower than the bottom of one-line comments, i.e. below the comment. You can see that your own comment—which you can't flag or upvote—only takes up one line.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I was blind, but now I see.

Comment: [Spaaaaaaaace!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWVGupqvCL8)

Comment: I have made [a feature request to move the flag icons next to the vote icons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243858/display-comment-flag-next-to-vote-instead-of-below-to-reduce-whitespace), as well as a user script that does it.

Comment: I'm fixing this on dev. I'm increasing comment font size to 13px and adjusted the padding a bit so it matches the spacing as the old meta.

Comment: +1 for "can't tell whats a link" - I had this problem several times now. Hint: 9% of all men are red-green blind ("weakness" would be a better term, because it's not a "complete" blindness)... It is really hard to distinguish the red color of the link from the other text. I often only find the links on SO by reading the context and *guessing* that there should be a link... Also thanks for the increase of comment font size, the current one is really hard to read on a 1600*1200px monitor... Pressing Strg+"Plus" increases the comments font size, but the other content gets too big then...

Comment: I agree with your comments except for the link underlying - links should be colored. For me underlined text is very distracting.

Comment: If anybody *is* interested in underlined links I threw together a userscript to add the style at https://github.com/JC3/Misc/blob/master/scripts/SO%20Underline%20Links.user.js (it will put a dotted underline under links in posts; does not touch comments).

Comment: @xxbbcc easy for you to say if you're not colour blind

Comment: @Cocowalla It'd be nice to have options. Links should stand out in more than one way - I'd support something like having a common image in front of the link, or bold links, etc. If underlying could be turned off in profiles, I'd be fine with underlines, too (since I'd just turn them off).

Comment: @jin isn't it weird that the upvote and flag icons are so close together from a UX perspective? I guess I find it strange that they have equal "real estate" space and location.  Flagging would seem really rare to me compared to upvoting.

Comment: @MichaelPryor I dunno, flagging comments is one of my favorite pastimes.

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/when-should-hyperlinks-be-underlined

Comment: "With space, no one can see much text on your screen".  Very bright with all that white but I suppose this allows fro room to zoom so the page can be adjusted by users to be easier to read.?  I give it a B/B- ....

Comment: Easy fix: put the upvote and flag buttons horizontally!

Comment: The comment gets shorter if you flag it. Mass-flag to get rid of whitespace!

Answer (score 204):

[Link text is still unreadable on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255983/change-color-of-inline-links-in-so) It looks like normal text unless you've visited it. (Hint: This has been a problem for a while; fix it while you're at it!)

The color on SO proper should also be addressed at this point too. It sounds like something trivial, but it's discouraging to link things in answers knowing the OP (and other users) have a high chance of not catching the fact they're links.

Other than that, looks great in my opinion. The sharper contrast in colors looks cleaner and more professional.

---

**EDIT**: Good to go :)

Comment: It's actually harder to read once you've visited it. It's a dark red when unvisited, and turns grey once you've visited. Really hard to tell it's a link.

Comment: you're totally right about the color. I left the link color the same dark maroon color as before for the time being. I'm definitely going to make it more readable in future patches.

Comment: This also affects username on comment thread. The first time I saw that, I was surprised thinking they were deleted.

Comment: You can kind of work around the issue by making the links bold. So instead of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help) they would look like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Links should be underlined. Why this fundamental UX fact is ignored so often nowadays is utterly beyond me.

Comment: We have [this problem on the main site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269539/make-visited-links-a-bit-more-visible/271977#271977), why bring it to meta as well? I agree that the links should, at a minimum, be underlined.

Comment: @Jin I propose a color-blind friendly `text-decoration: underline` on links in posts and comments. The rest is pretty obviously clickable (usernames and timestamps, the `share`, `edit`, `flag` buttons, etc). But I think this looks reasonably good while providing a clear UX benefit. http://i.imgur.com/xNhmPZF.png

Comment: I second @SecondRikudo as a colorblind user. WIth the current design update, I honestly cannot tell what's regular text and what's a clickable link. Please either choose another color for links, or add `text-decoration` to them.

Comment: Good contrast is important for everyone. Color combinations that may appear sufficiently distinguishable on a designer's expensive, calibrated display may look very different under the variety of conditions experienced in the real world (bad color reproduction, less-than-ideal viewing angles, bright sunlight on mobile devices, etc). Starting with extra contrast increases the chances that the difference will still be noticeable.

Comment: I am personally a fan of having links underlined with a dashed line.  Makes it distinct from underlining for emphasis, but still clear to everybody that there's something different there.

Comment: @Ajean I like that idea, but I also fear that sucz a link would look like one of those automatic generated context ads found on many pages...

Comment: I'm red-green colorblind too, and I actually didn't notice the link in the answer until I saw the screenshot in @Second Rikudo's comment.

Comment: This should probably be historically locked rather than closed, IMO.

Answer (score 144):

Please change the color of the "close" option on the *share this post* popup:

> [image: share popup screenshot]

---

Also, can we please have better alignment of the scores on the answers tab of our profile page?

> [image]

---

The highlighted item in the help section needs a new color:

> [image]

---

The font size in my flag history is weird:

> [image]

The font size on the main site flag history is uniform:

> [image]

---

Font size on ["Recent Hot Answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-completed/info) is too big:

> [image]

---

[Upvoted comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/277235#comment119128_277212) look weird, the [number and the arrow/flag icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/277235#comment119090_277210) isn't aligned properly, please fix it.

> [image]

Alignment with flag:

> [image]

Comment: will fix in next build.

Comment: Thanks @Jin, I will keep adding new suggestions in this post as I come across them :)

Comment: mah, just delete this and post a new one, since Jin love all those ---pings--- messages in the inbox

Comment: I explained why the hover effect doesn't work on visited links [in my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277216). It's only broken for *some* links though.

Comment: Thanks @animuson, I removed it from my post to reduce redundancy and length.

Answer (score 128):

EDIT:  No guys, seriously, **fix the links.**  They're getting a bit too difficult to read.

It feels kind of...clean.  MSO's got its business suit and tie on, and it's doing its best to impress. But it also feels sterile in some areas.  I'm not saying that's a bad thing, but some things are going to definitely need tweaking.

I'm looking exclusively at this page, and I see a handful of oddities.  Xubuntu 14.04, Chrome 39.0.2171.62 beta (64-bit).

- The vote count divider is noticeably wider than what one would be "used" to.  Below are the screenshots for reference - on the left is Stack Overflow as it is today.  It's also kind of awkward that there's so much more space between it and the vote counts.

> [image]                  [image]

- Is there any good reason to set the reputation of users as this kind of faded gray?  It's the same color you're using for visited links for whatever odd reason.

> [image]

- Speaking of links, why not reintroduce the dashed styling for links?  I could appreciate that it's borrowing from Meta's theme, but Meta can partially get away with what it's doing because its primary color is blue, not...gray.  This issue extends to the revision number below; if you don't have a decent monitor or you can't really distinguish between shades of gray, you're going to have a fun time telling which version MSO is on.

> [image]
>   [image]

- I just noticed that favorites are *bright*.  This isn't very readable.

> [image]

Comment: Can you please put the first images in a blockquote? I clicked on the screenshots to upvote your answer...

Comment: I agree that the yellow color in the *favorites* falls into the "avoid contrast only in the blue channel" trap.

Comment: wait... i only see overall score. is separate upvote/downvote counts something i need to unlock with more reputation?

Comment: @Woodrow You require 1k reputation to see vote counts.

Answer (score 86):

(Check the revision for **fixed** bugs)

1. Vote count overflow in the sidebar **[FIXED]**
2. Jon Skeet's problem (preemptive)

   [image]

   I modified the badge count in the DOM inspector to check whether it has space for high count of badges.
3. Pagination is located at a weird position **[FIXED]**
4. The tags are **1px** too close to their description on the [tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags). Although it is only 1px, it is enough to cause the impressions that they are closer than they should be.

   [image]

   Overlay for comparison

   [image]
5. Misaligned drop-down on favorite tag/ignored tag

   [image]

   The same problem on main site, but the difference is not as striking.

   There are also too much space between "Ignored tags" and the box.
6. Misaligned vote count in list of posts (e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/design/new)

   [image]

   There are also too much spaces to the left.

   On the main site, the vote count has a colored background, but the new design make the background white, so the number looks floating.
7. On home page, the color is not applied to the numbers on questions with high view **[FIXED]**
8. On [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), the check mark is misaligned **[FIXED]**, and the space to the right for the names seems to be lacking **[FIXED]**, causing it to wrap to the next line.
9. [Contact page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)

   [image]
10. Quote starting a post breaks the preview **[FIXED]**

Comment: +1 for number 3 (I was actually thinking about posting that issue myself).  That bar should be over to the left or right IMO, not floating where it is.

Comment: Jon Skeets problem is that he still does not have 1M reputation. This would give more pixels for badges.

Comment: SO should definitely offer you a JOB in QA :D

Answer (score 77):

The `<textarea>` for posting questions and answers now uses a variable-width font instead of the traditional fixed-width font. This might not be the end of the world for Meta where we don't often post code (though I don't like it), but it would be *totally* inappropriate for the main site.

[image: Screenshot of editor]

Please bring back the fixed-width font.

Comment: The stolen mono-spaced font for the editor is causing me major problems when typing nicely formatted code snippets. I'm now less motivated to give well worked out answers and put lots of effort into them. Quick-shot answers it will be in future (if any at all). SO quality will go down through this (because I'm not the only one loosing motivation when seeing how this change rides roughshod with us and our efforts).

Comment: Seriously, this cannot be overstated. As Kurt says, code formatting is *much* more difficult. But on top of that, ASCII diagrams (which can be incredibly useful in a question/answer) are almost impossible (for a very simple example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27974486/1287251) is improved with the arrows that highlight the mistake; monospaced text is a must!).

Comment: _Please_ don't use HTML entities for writing code! Use backticks!!!

Answer (score 58):

1. Can I haz borderz around tag scores?

   > [image]

   With current design, such a look would be very good:

   > [image]
2. Answers with score <-7 are no longer greyed out. But should be (?)
3. Beep. Buggy tabs:

   > [image]
4. Selected and non-selected stars have slightly different designs. Also, text (number of starrers) under selected star is normal, while non-selected star has bold text under it. This text should be also centered to the star.

   > [image]
5. Can top bar use a larger resolution of my avatar?

   [image]

Comment: Yes, blue borders please :P

Comment: Those borders looks good! Ad point 2, didn't you mean *Answers with score <= -3*. Or is this fade-out limit different here on meta ?

Comment: @TLama <2 on main, <7 on meta, yep :)

Comment: haha point 5, a personal request

Comment: @Joop Not a personal; this applies for every user.

Comment: @nicael To be fair, it *only* applies if you zoom right in.

Comment: @cyber It can be felt on high-res screens, I am just exaggerating it a bit to let you understand what I mean.

Comment: @nicael but how (and why ;-) ) did you notice that?

Comment: [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417215/...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417215/remove-the-30-day-time-out-on-display-name-changes

Answer (score 49):

I like it, especially the black and white look of the icons in the answer-editor.

One thing that still irritates me (and I know it's a huge thing to fix) is all the wasted whitespace. I run at 2560x1440 and I run Chrome in fullscreen, so I might notice this even more because of that but still the main column with content is only 728px on my screen.

[image]

(Yes, I run Lotus Notes. No, it's not my decision)

Would it be possible to utilise at least some of this whitespace I've marked? The center column with the main content is actually fine, from what I know 50-75 characters per line is considered fairly optimal for reading. But the sidebar.... the sidebar feels really cramped, maybe it could be wider on bigger resolutions rather then stacking as it does now?

Comment: +1, a common solution is to let the body of the page scale itself according to the screen width. An easy solution to avoid dealing with thousands of special cases (ie. huge screen) is to define a `min-width` & `max-width`. ie. `min-width: 728px; ` & `max-width: 1200px`. It's smth that can be implemented step by step, page-type by page-type (ie. first on the profile page, then question page, etc). Done that for a bunch of websites & it works like a charm. Then if mobile support is needed you add media queries to do the same, ie. for mobile, you'd have `min-width: 320px; ` & `max-width: 600px`.

Comment: An alternative would be to put the comments to the right of each answer rather than below it, if the user's screen is wide enough.  But that may be too fiddly to get right.  By all means set min and max widths but better to define them as ems rather than pixels (even allowing for the fact that 'pixel' these days is something of a fiction).

Comment: Even in 1920 x 1080 there's quite a lot of space on each side.

Comment: Screens keep getting wider but web designers keep going taller; I have never understood why that is. I've found that the vast majority of web sites look much better if you turn your screen on its side and rotate the display...

Comment: @JasonC I suspect mobile support to be the cause of this effect. On a phone, the screen is usually not very wide but tall and we all know that the mobile users are the ones to attract... sadly.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yeah, but the mobile version is a completely different site, independent of this one. *shakes fist*

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau There is 12% of whitespace on each side( 24% together )  even in 1280x1024. I guess it makes some sense on a wider monitor because you can have two windows side by side.

Comment: [Sorry guys, but not even close :P](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPBj.png)

Comment: @NathanOsman Don't make me set up my triple-screen :)

Comment: +10 million for fluid design, both expanding to fill wide screens and contracting on narrow ones. Don't try to tell me how big my browser window should be by forcing horizontal scrollbars on me, or adding huge blank margins. Adjust to fit the space.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You know, it is a good thing lines are a consistent width. Otherwise, how should you wrap code-blocks? Especially, how should you easily recognize that your lines are too damn long? Because I personally hate horizontal scrolling, double so for code.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The usual rules apply: Keep code lines under 80 characters. If someone chooses to have their browser window too narrow, they'll have to scroll. (It's no coincidence that this is exactly what you have to do on Stack Overflow at present.) Could easily add a warning if someone is writing really long code lines because their browser is really wide, but people already do that.

Comment: You need to rotate your monitor. My set up is 2 horizontal monitors, one on top of the other, and 2 vertical monitors off either side. Stack Overflow is normally open on the left vertical monitor.

Comment: I think the extra whitespace on wide monitors and the missing padding on tablets are part of the same problem - a rigid layout that completely fails to adjust to the space available. Reflow to fit browser window size was a solved problem in the earliest days of HTML, so why can't SO do it?

Answer (score 45):

(I'm using Firefox 31 on Windows 7)

Could the vote counts for questions and answers be moved to the right just a little?  They seem too close to the left edge of the page.

Here is an example of how they currently look:

[image]

I propose that they be moved just a little to something like:

[image]

As you see, the vote count is now centered between the left edge of the page and the question text.

Comment: completely disagree. feels like some "print-design" suggestion (vs web-design).

Comment: Yes, this. The arrows are mashed up against the left edge of my iPad screen now, and I don't like it.

Comment: This isn't a problem on larger resolutions; I'm on 1280x1024 and there's at least two and a half inches of screen space to the left of the vote count. PS you're a few FF versions behind

Comment: It's more annoying with bounties: [styling of vote count/bounty award has insufficient padding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287241/1048572)

Answer (score 37):

**No. I do not like the new style.**

- The main page is better.
  Maybe links are too little highlighted, but I like the red mouse-hover.
- The input box sucks.

  > [image]
- I do not like vote counts.

  > [image]
- Everything is too spaced out.

  > [image]
- The flag summary's new style is useless.

  > [image]

Comment: **+ 1** for *'the input box sucks'*. It sucks mainly because of the theft of the mono-spaced font, making it so much harder to type in nicely formatted code snippets.

Answer (score 33):

The "Ask Question" button and the question-filtering buttons should not all be grouped together. They are for unrelated purposes and grouping them all together hides the "Ask Question" button from people who ignore the "big group of buttons at the top".

Good grouping:

[image: Good button grouping]

The question-filtering buttons are clearly above the question list to which they apply, and are obviously separate from the Ask button.

Bad grouping:

[image: Bad button grouping]

The question-filtering buttons are not above the question list, and where did the 'Ask' button go? (I know it's there at the right, but it took a while to notice)

Comment: It just took me a switch back to the main SO page and then back here because I literally overlooked the *Ask question* button! I was already wondering if meta was temporarily in read-only mode...

Comment: The "Ask" button _should_ be harder to find. Users should be browsing existing questions before deciding they need to write their own.

Answer (score 32):

Review is... kind of broken right now.

> [image]

Note the title and body are offset, and the question info table is *way* down at the bottom (too far down to get a screenshot of).

The review history page also looks weird:

> [image]

The titles are bold... which seems out of place. The questions that are deleted are normal size, making it seem way out of proportion.

Other than that, nice job.

Comment: will fix in the next build.

Comment: Great! Did I say how much we love you, @Jin? ;)

Comment: I'm surprised by the lack of eeeeekk comments. Is this real life? (I think I just jinxed myself)

Comment: Yep, it's still real life @Jin. I know because the bacon is right over there.

Answer (score 32):

Would it be possible to get improved code block and blockquote formatting? Right now, they look very similar. This has been [requested before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270612/526741). Using as an example:

```
> This is a blockquote with `some awesome code` in it

    This is a codeblock
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: Current design of blockquotes and code blocks]

It would be great if something like this were implemented:

[image: Suggested design of blockquotes and code blocks]

This makes it easier to differentiate between code blocks and blockquotes, as well as between code and text in blockquotes. I'm fairly confident a similar design is used on other SE sites, but I'm not sure which ones. (I have this set up as a user style in Firefox currently, but I think others would benefit from it.)

One thing to look out for is the colors for spoilers:

> Text `code`

Comment: This is exactly how it is on the beta sites (not sure about the spoilers).  It is definitely easier to tell the difference between a quote and a codeblock. *And* CodeBlocks inside of quote blocks look awesome this way too.

Answer (score 30):

On the revisions page, there are arrows missing that indicate a revision can be expanded/collapsed. Is this intentional?

Meta:

[image: Meta Arrows]

Vs. SO

[image: SO]

Comment: We need the arrows. Please bring them back.

Answer (score 27):

It's **too gray**. I understand that meta aims to be visually different by being more gray than the main site, but this is just too much.

The contrast of some areas is very bad; for example take the placeholder texts of inputs. They're barely visible. Similar, the link color is hardly distinguishable from text color. This might look great in theory and certain environments, but fails in practice. Don't forget to consider bad monitors, low-contrast displays, and screens with dark backlights.

The layout changes are nice (except those that are complained about in the other answers), but please fix the color scheme.

Comment: +1 feels like being back in the 50's a little bit. It'd be nice if it was intended, but it obviously is not. Maybe I should simply get this as a monitor :D http://www.monitech.com/images/426_12MONO_CRT_2.png

Comment: Personally, I absolutely love the grey...

Answer (score 27):

> **It may take a little getting used to...**

Urrm no - I doubt I'll be able to get used to it.

I have a visual impairment which means I have to sit with my face about 6-8 inches from my computer screen and that was with SO and SO meta as they were. The changes to fonts, font colour etc, mean I'm seriously struggling to read anything at all.

Sure there are screen "magnifier" apps and "TTS readers" but I don't need them for decent websites or apps and I don't intend to start using them now.

Why do UI designers assume all users have "normal" sight? Art for art's sake is not a valid rationale for UI design. You might as well have taken a wheelchair access ramp from the front of a building and replaced it with stairs as far as I'm concerned.

Seriously - my face is about 4-5 inches from my screen as I type this and I'm having to squint in order to read what I'm typing.

I don't care about logos or other pretty things - do what you like with them. Just make the sites readable again - if it ain't broke, don't try to fix it. Everything was fine as it was before.

Comment: I also find the font changes very hard on my eyes on my laptop and my 27 inch lcd it is forcing me to sit closer to the monitor.

Comment: I used to read SO at home on my tiny laptop screen at normal content size (`[ctrl]-[0]`) but now zoom in one level on the client (`[ctrl]-[+]`) to get the same comfort.

Comment: I wish I could really uproot this - This is the BEST description of the issues I have with the new design. I like the poster read very close to the screen, and I do not need assertive apps for any sites - so needing now I think is a problem with the site. One way to make it betterto increase the font size only and keep the icons etc the same size but I have already been told that StackExchange does not support this

Answer (score 26):

For the comments section's font I prefer the existing one. In the new theme it seems little unreadable to the naked eye.

Old design
[image]

New design
[image]

Comment: I had to grab a measuring tool and compare the fonts; the new one is only slightly smaller but it *feels* tiny.

Comment: I like it, it is more compact and still readable, saving some space. Just the whitespace on the bottom must be removed.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to explain that the first image is the *old* design and the second image the *new* design?

Answer (score 26):

This has been around for a while, but can we fix the alignment of the comment upvote arrow while updating everything else? Notice the helpful straight line I added - the arrows don't line up when the number in front has a different number of digits.

[image]

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't observe it till I read your answer.

Comment: Neither did I, suggesting that this isn't actually a problem.

Answer (score 26):

I've seen lots of useful feedback here, but so far no one seems to have mentioned what for me is the most troubling change (indeed, for me the only troubling change, though I do agree less whitespace in the layout would be better). That is, that the "visited" color of links is practically the same as the "not visited" color.

**Not visited:**
[image]
**Visited:**
[image]

On my computer, and especially on a page with dozens of other questions, it is nearly impossible to tell the difference.

Maybe there's some feature on StackOverflow I'm not aware of that addresses this. Either a better way to know what questions I've read/reviewed already other than seeing the "visited" state of the link, or a way to override the link state colors?

If so, then maybe this isn't such a big problem. If only I could know what the alternatives are. But if I'm already tracking what I've seen on StackOverflow in the best way possible, there needs to be much more contrast between the two link states.

**Addendum (workaround):**
IMHO, this really should be fixed at the StackOverflow level, i.e. in the design itself. However, a little snooping of the HTML document tree provides the information one needs in order to create a style sheet to override the visited link color (a feature I believe most if not all web browsers support, at least on the desktop).

Just create a .css file with the following (or if you already have a custom style sheet, add this to it):

```
div.question-summary a.question-hyperlink:visited
{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Then assign that .css file as your custom style sheet.

In Internet Explorer, you can do this by opening the "Internet options" dialog, clicking the "Accessibility" button at the bottom, checking the box that reads "Format documents using my style sheet", and then entering the path for your .css file in the edit box below the checkbox. You will need to close and restart the browser for the new setting to take effect.

I don't have the specifics for other browsers off the top of my head, but I assume the detail can be easily found for someone who wants them.

Naturally, customize the above to suit your needs:

- I used "red" as the color here, to make the color change unmistakable. Of course, change this color to whatever you want (either a valid named color, or a #RGB-style color value)
- The above limits the change to setting the color of the visited header links on the question-list page. You can of course use the same technique to override the color choices (or other formatting choices, for that matter) for other page elements. Just inspect the displayed HTML for the page you want to customize to find the correct element type, class, or other attribute you want to select.

Comment: +100 they should also bring back underlines on hover as well !

Comment: +maxint, the rest one can _probably_ get used to - but this is going to be a real problem for me. And the difference on meta is somewhat more noticeable, so it couldn't even be easily predicted from the preview.

Comment: If anyone sees this without seeing the other question about it, [you can find my new color recommendations here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283697/change-highlighting-for-read-topics#comment143528_283697) and override them manually for now (using something like Stylish).

Answer (score 24):

The vertical offset for `<sup>` is a little ridiculous.

[image]

Here's the relevant css:

```
sup {
    font-size: 80%;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4em;
}
```

Comment: How do you do bold inside a code block, like in that last css snippet ?

Comment: Don't have enough rep to edit on meta.. Will figure it out though :-)

Answer (score 23):

1. You need to switch the `.question-hyperlink:hover` and `.question-hyperlink:visited` rules around. Currently, the hover is before the visited, so the visited always overrides the hover, which means the visited will never get the hover effect. Flopping their positions would let visited links have the same hover effect. Same goes for the `.answer-hyperlink` styles. Footer links are also affected. Not sure what other hyperlink styles might be affected. The plain `a` elements are functioning correctly though.
2. Why are the vote arrows *orange* on Meta? Shouldn't they be dark red or something on Meta and orange on Main? Is the orange just a preview of what they will look like on Stack Overflow? I'm cool with it if it will be fixed in the final release. Just struck me as weird.
3. When discarding a draft, the "draft discarded" text overlaps a line. Both the "draft saved" and "draft discarded" text are crazily small and unnoticeable.

   > [image: Draft Discarded]
4. Images in posts have a `margin-bottom: 1em` on them? That looks kind of weird, especially in a blockquote (like directly above this). I've never seen that style applied to images on any site before.
5. The post links are spaced a bit close together.

   > [image: Post Links]
6. When viewing the mod menu on a post, the new tab styles connect with the exit button in the top right corner (probably the most minor thing I could complain about).

   > [image: Mod Menu Tabs]
7. Why do the tags have a blue border? Did someone copy-paste CSS from the default beta theme?

   > [image: Blue Border on Tags]
8. The notice boxes for the closed, deleted, etc notices stick out past the post container. This is much more noticeable when the post is deleted and the boxes go past the red background.

   > [image: Notices Boxes Expanding Past Container]

Comment: Regarding #2: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update#comment119085_277210

Answer (score 22):

On a Kindle Fire the page is not padded out well from the left side:

> [image]

Comment: +1 adding some media query to add a bit of left padding for tablet-sized device coul help

Comment: +1 I'll comment here instead of posting a related answer this is the same on a iPad.  There is not enough padding on both sides, it feels like I'm zoomed in and text is cut off.

Comment: Same thing happens on iPhone - zero left margin.

Comment: Chrome on Android - same problem.

Comment: Or even just in a browser window that isn't very wide. Basically, there's no padding on the page, and there should be (a little bit, just a few pixels). Also: [Fluid layout please!!!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277229/157247).

Comment: I can confirm this for Firefox on Windows 7.  Given my OS window border settings, my Firefox window has to be at least 1032 pixels wide in order to get 1 pixel separating the Stack Overflow logo and the left window border.  1031 pixels or less and there is no separation at all.  Really, no matter how narrow the window is, there is no good reason to have zero padding.

Answer (score 22):

The favorite star's active state doesn't have a clean, uniform border. It looks like someone tried to scale the entire shape down... leaving an inconsistent thickness around the edge. That and it looks like there's a leftover polygon in there.

[image]

Comment: Related (point 4): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277221/616460

Answer (score 21):

I was also very shocked at the different looking refresh.

A few things I noticed:

- The "Asked"/"Viewed"/"Active" lines are **really** far apart. You could drive a car between them. It's at least twice as big as the current spacing on Stack Overflow.
- The "comment upvote" button is very small. I immediately thought "I'm going to have a hard time hitting that" when I tried to use it. In fact; *all* the buttons seem a bit smaller; the comment upvote more than others.

  - The arrow tip is also above the number; which just looks *weird*.
- "Post Your Answer" appears to be the only "3D" button on the page.

  - Just noticed "Add Comment" is also 3D
- The comment text entry area is HUGE. The font is twice as big as the posted comment. Not sure if that's intentional or not.

  - The box left edge is also very far from the left of the post compared to the right edge of the button and the right edge of the post. It makes it look imbalanced.

The site looks really clean overall, just a bit of "UI shock" probably :)

Comment: The bolded titles were annoying and the rest of Stack Exchange sites have moved away from them. They don't need to be bolded, nor should they be.

Comment: @animuson That one is obviously not a bug; I just liked the feature :)

Comment: Removing the feature request; I still liked it though...

Comment: Regarding the comment text entry: 1: "area is HUGE" -> I kinda like that, always been annoyed to only have to expand the text area manually. 2: "The font is twice as big as the posted comment. Not sure if that's intentional or not." -> Completely agree! 3: "The box left edge is also very far from the left of the post compared to the right edge of the button and the right edge of the post. It makes it look imbalanced" -> Completelty agree. 4: The "edit comment" module/component is not aligned with the "add comment" module/component. see http://i.imgur.com/CEej2IQ.png

Comment: @AdrienBe Nice catch! Haven't tried editing a comment so I missed the last one.

Comment: Agreed on the comment font size! I like that the area is now bigger, but the font size shrinking from when I type to when the comment is posted feels ... disconcerting.

Answer (score 17):

H2 and H3 are not significant enough in style difference.

## h1

### h2

#### h3

> [image]

I've often found myself using h2 and h3 because h1 was *too* imposing in the past.  This isn't as much of a problem now, but the h2 and h3 don't seem different enough.  When I've used them in recent post I've found that I need to use (lack of) capitalization of the text in addition the header level to indicate the level of the header:

### This is h2

#### this is h3

because the difference between:

### This is h2

#### This is h3

wasn't significant enough to determine if the h3 was a subheader under the previous h2 or a new header at the same level as the h2.

---

Consider:

### Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Ut tincidunt fermentum turpis id interdum. Fusce malesuada cursus dignissim. Proin consequat, arcu in convallis porta, risus lectus malesuada libero, quis tempus lorem lorem a ligula. Suspendisse viverra risus ut urna suscipit, quis sodales mi molestie. Donec dolor est, accumsan ac facilisis a, molestie in ipsum.

#### Maecenas ultrices dolor sit amet metus placerat, euismod congue ante pharetra.

Quisque fermentum ut ante nec pretium. Praesent efficitur sem lorem, id varius nisi ullamcorper in. Curabitur tristique ultricies magna ut dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis mollis, augue vel lacinia gravida, ante ipsum tempor turpis, a rhoncus eros justo et augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis mattis ultrices dui, congue scelerisque ipsum semper eget. Etiam at mattis lorem, sit amet varius justo. Etiam commodo dui odio, sed luctus augue luctus eget. Curabitur mattis ultrices tempor.

#### In dictum rhoncus neque et efficitur. Duis dictum mollis suscipit.

Duis eu nisl quam. Praesent tristique justo vitae pulvinar imperdiet. Nunc viverra, ante at aliquam eleifend, elit arcu euismod ante, vel ullamcorper turpis ante ac nulla. Nullam ac varius eros, eget semper augue. Pellentesque ac sapien ac orci ultricies lacinia. Morbi eleifend, mi at porttitor efficitur, tortor nibh posuere nibh, quis lobortis odio ante at lacus.

### Nam justo metus, ultrices sed massa ut, aliquet lacinia lorem.

Mauris sapien elit, iaculis vitae sapien quis, sollicitudin mattis metus. Pellentesque consectetur, metus ut gravida gravida, odio mi rhoncus felis, bibendum mollis augue leo eget metus. Integer consectetur justo volutpat ligula auctor, et suscipit velit interdum. Aenean euismod sit amet enim non hendrerit. Phasellus faucibus nulla sed posuere cursus. In lectus lacus, interdum imperdiet sapien vel, egestas convallis lacus. Vivamus ullamcorper nunc vel felis feugiat, vitae sollicitudin lacus ultrices.

### Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi tincidunt lorem at finibus dapibus.

Proin arcu neque, elementum quis dignissim vel, semper elementum orci. Praesent id faucibus nisi, quis placerat urna. Donec pretium porttitor aliquet. Vestibulum ex magna, tincidunt sit amet varius sed, vestibulum ut lacus. Nunc dignissim libero ut diam elementum pellentesque.

#### Phasellus risus dolor, efficitur sed cursus eget, lacinia ac massa.

Curabitur vel pretium leo. Maecenas congue est eget neque consectetur ultricies. Quisque non velit vel lorem semper porta. Morbi sagittis consectetur dolor vitae faucibus. Nulla fringilla ullamcorper eros. Aenean lobortis nunc sit amet erat cursus, sed luctus ipsum consequat. Nunc sit amet dui orci. In ut tempor nisl.

---

Looking at the above passage, can you quickly identify which are the h2 and which are the h3?

Comment: I thought the first h3 was just a one-sentence paragraph. :/ I think the problem is less with the distinction between h2 and h3... and more with the distinction between h3 and the paragraph text.

Comment: Agree with canon. If headings used bold font this would be less of an issue.

Answer (score 16):

When editing a post, the tags look dull: just a nondescript grey circle in them (maybe a missing image):

[image]

Only when hovering the mouse over them do you get an actual image:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

**Edit:** [Fixed now.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283842/1412059)

---

I don't have a problem if you change the colours for syntax highlighting, but please keep them consistent. Let's use the R language as an example. Colours used to be quite different for numbers/strings and keywords. Now they are almost impossible to distinguish. Example:

```r
f <- function(x) 42
```

`function` and `42` actually have different colours, but it's really hard to see that. Please fix the colour scheme of syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yep - we're sorry about this, definitely not an intentional change.

Answer (score 15):

Me gusta.

Couple of things (note: I'm not a designer, this is just the stuff that I found slightly quirky):

- Perhaps the buttons (add comment / post answer) should be made flat? They look different from the rest of the site, which was the case in the previous design as well and a bit strange. Now that tags are flat too, I think the buttons should follow suit.
- Community bulletin might need some shifting downwards. Maybe.
- Margins on the text area make it feel like there's additional space which I need to remove, but I suspect that's just me being used to the old design

Also, the ask question page has two issues:

[image]

Firstly, the help question mark is floating in the wrong place (Firefox, Ubuntu).

Secondly, the "Title: <textbox>" part looks a tad off — it might be better if the title part was *above* the textbox, rather than next to it (like the layout of the tags box)

---

**Edit:**

The markdown help box is still off a couple months later on Firefox (35.0.1). Here's a couple pics to demonstrate the problem and a quick fix suggestion:

[image: Markdown help opened up]

Changing the pixels on inline styles from:

```html
<li class="wmd-button wmd-help-button active-help" id="wmd-help-button" style="right: 0px; left: 639px;" title="Markdown Editing Help">
  [...]
</li>
<div class="mdhelp" id="mdhelp" style="right: 0px; width: 672px; top: 41px;">
  [...]
</div>
```

to:

```html
<li class="wmd-button wmd-help-button active-help" id="wmd-help-button" style="right: 0px; left: 626px;" title="Markdown Editing Help">
  [...]
</li>
<div class="mdhelp" id="mdhelp" style="right: -13px; width: 660px; top: 41px;">
  [...]
</div>
```

Helps fix the position, but the border on the right and left side of the Markdown help box are still lighter than the input box as a whole.

[image: Markdown help quick fix]

Comment: What OS/Browser/ver are you using? I noticed the (?) icon is off.

Comment: @Jin Firefox 32.0.3 on Ubuntu. It's also off on my trunk build of Firefox.

Comment: Weird, but I always have a problem finding flat buttons on SO, of course it's just a second or two a delay but 3Dish buttons are much more obvious for me.

Comment: @Jin Added some more details in the answer about the markdown help issue.

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed...

Answer (score 15):

Yay, less bad!

.mainnav's color contrast is 3.37:1. That's too low. Me no can see. Make it 5 at least since it's… *the .mainnav*.

Post body text is kinda big, comparing it to the text in this textarea and the tags and .post-menu anchors. Make the small things less small, and the big post body text less big. The vote count especially should be substantially larger.

Comment: To follow up on that WCAG 2.0 (AAA) says at least 7:1 or (AA) 4.5:1. This can matter a lot for people with less-than-optimal eyesight. See [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast) and [online tool](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html) for checking contrast.

Comment: It matters a lot to people without disabilities too, *I* can't easily read it.

Answer (score 15):

Please put the horizontal lines back in the comments section. It did a lot for my ability to scan the comments, and that feature is gone now. If they're still there, please make them more visible.

Comment: They are still there, they are just less visible now. I agree that they should be darker. They are so light now that sitting slightly above eye-level with a non-IPS monitor can render them invisible.

Comment: Wow, I had to go back and look when TylerH said they were still there, because I didn't remember them. They're *really close* to invisible.

Answer (score 15):

I don't want to say any layout is better than the other one, but there are a few things I'd like to have changed on the new layout:

1. Why is there so many space? For example here in the StackSnippet, I don't need that big buttons:
   [image]
   On the old layout, the buttons were smaller, but there was very much useless padding, and there is even much padding left:
   [image]
   And this is for most buttons here so, for example, the one to upload an image is equivalent, but the button to post an answer has a much smaller text size in it. Please don't make the buttons look so different.
2. The new tags look very ugly. This is just a very very light gray box with a very very small border around it (except for required or mod-only tags like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)):
   <kbd>[image]</kbd>
3. The border when posting an answer doesn't have any effect on pictures. **The worse thing is that this is still like that after I posted my answer!!!** Here is an example from my answer:
   <kbd>[image]</kbd>
   Please note that the images are all wrongly assigned the same way, so there must be an invisible border right to the visible border where the images are shrinked as they probably should.
4. As already mentioned by many other answers, I really dislike the new vote layout. Please use the old one again, I really liked the vote images on the old layout
5. I really dislike the new Stack Overflow logo. The old one looked so much better than the new one:
   [image]
6. The comment post box is very much too big, and has too much padding:
   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

**The new layout looks to much like Windows 8 to me.** But I'm sure you can improve it so that it doesn't always remind me on that bloody OS.

I use Mozilla [SeaMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaMonkey) on [Debian K-Wheezy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Sarge_release_.282005.E2.80.93present.29).

Comment: You know the comment box is resizeable, right? Although I **really** want to be able to re-size the box laterally as well as vertically.

Comment: @TylerH Yes I know that my browser supports resizing all textareas (no matter if the webpage allows) but I think the default size is too big

Answer (score 15):

Now I'm barely able to see **the difference between read and unread questions** in the list, especially with my crappy monitor, unless I move the mouse over them.

This is the most annoying thing with the update, and Jakob Nielsen would probably have a couple of things to say about it.

Comment: If anyone sees this without seeing the other question about it, [you can find my new color recommendations here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283697/change-highlighting-for-read-topics#comment143528_283697) and override them manually for now (using something like Stylish).

Answer (score 13):

Can this *please* be a little more grayscale -- or at least a different color than Stack Overflow? Switching sites, each has a different design. Metas are usually grayscale. But when going from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow... there isn't too much of a difference, color scheme wise. It looks the same.

Can we get at least some visual indicator (other than the logo) that we changed sites and went to meta?

Comment: I just notice the icons in the sprite are not gray scale. I'll be updating that tomorrow.

Comment: @Jin nice. Out of curiousity: which icons are we talking about?

Comment: No! Grey makes it seem evil and horrible.

Comment: @hichris123 for example, the active state of the up vote arrow, favorite star, comment upvote, (x)close icons.

Comment: I will state, that setting the background color for posts and the main body to `#F5F5F5` actually looks pretty good...

Comment: Yeah! Evil and horrible. Like meta. @bjb568

Comment: @Makoto That does look nice. Might userscript it if it stays white.

Comment: Meh, colors help people process information better. Fine, make it a different color, but not greyscale.

Answer (score 13):

When using search, accepted answer highlighting truncates the score box:

[image: Truncated score box]

It particularly stands out as odd when mixed with [results that include questions and unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=consensus).

Comment: Oh. Linked images (such as the one in the answer) need to be underlined and/or clearly indicated. There's a link in the final paragraph that's not obvious as well. (I'm guessing there are other answers that provide that feedback.)

Answer (score 13):

Why are comments so ***tiny***? No offense, but I don't really want to up the zoom in my browser just to read the comments. (chrome ver. 38.0.2125.111)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Comment vote count colors seem off (I know this was mentioned in a comment on the question, not *100%* confident that it hasn't already been mentioned in an answer; sorry if so):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Notice they fade to red in the 20s-30s but then head back to black. The fading back to black doesn't seem right. I expected redder (and possibly bold) for higher vote counts.

This seems to have changed, by the way, since the time this feedback post was originally created. Right after the announcement was made I didn't see any red in there at all. I might be mis-remembering. It looks like some red was added back in, but only in the middle range (shown above) and not the upper range.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Too much whitespace]

Decrease margin:

- Around voting/starring controls, between arrow and number too
- Around the migrated banner
- On the left of the page
- Between editor and OP
- Between "asked", "viewed", and "active"
- Between the right edge of text and the container of the featured/hot meta posts and related questions
- On the right of the comments

Not sure what to do with the nav, it looks weird. Maybe a border-radius on the links.

Comment: Very ugly screenshot

Comment: The “asked”, “viewed” and “active” margins seem ridiculously big to me. I cannot see the whole featured and hot posts box from initial viewport anymore.

Answer (score 12):

I stumbled upon another bug which I've looked for already in the answers here, but not found.  When viewing the upvotes/downvotes, if the up or downvote number is too large the plus sign/minus sign disappears.

[image: What happened to the minus sign?][image: And the plus sign...]

That looks like 59 upvotes and ... 110 red upvotes?

**IN ADDITION:**
Having recently asked a question with the new style on the main site, I was quite discomfited by the difference in font size and line wrapping between the editor window and the resulting post - I like to format my code so that horizontal scroll bars aren't necessary, but the editor wraps *before* that:

[image]

For simple code like this it was okay, but more complicated code would start to look awful in the editor window.... (Firefox 35.0.1)

Answer (score 12):

From [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283729/621962), you can see that stacking margins are a little ridiculous:

[image]

<sub>There's actually another `<p>` wrapping the `<sub>` but that's not part of the issue.</sub>

To reduce this gap, we could add the following rule:

```
.post-text img:last-child, .wmd-preview img:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what (if anything) to do about `<sub>`.

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The web icon is smaller and fuzzier, I presume that has to do with the conversion to SVG. I happened to have an old tab next to a new one so I could do a direct comparison, new on the left and old on the right:

[image: tab icon comparison]

This is with Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: I didn't notice it, but you're right. Right now one wouldn't recognize what does webicon represent if didn't know the original SO icon.

Comment: I agree, the new favicon is very blurry and small.

Answer (score 12):

One bothersome problem with the changes you put in place overnight.  The contrast between questions you've viewed and those you've not viewed is virtually nonexistent.  This significantly hinders usability.  (As does the new fonts, etc.)

Comment: If anyone sees this without seeing the other question about it, [you can find my new color recommendations here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283697/change-highlighting-for-read-topics#comment143528_283697) and override them manually for now (using something like Stylish).

Answer (score 11):

Is it just me, or did MSO get fatter?

The entire UI looks wider than it does on SO. This is especially noticeable if you toggle tabs between MSO and SO, looking at the top bar.

This gets quite annoying when toggling between SE tabs, as every other site (to my knowledge) is 990px, and now SO is 1030px.

Comment: It's fatter for me too

Comment: I think the UI should be still wider. Current design was made when majority monitors were 4:3. Now almost everyone has 16:9. Ratios must change too. Otherwise we are wasting precious screen real estate.

Comment: @Krumia I'm not saying it's *bad*. I'm just notifying them of the difference, in case it wasn't intentional.

Comment: It's not fatter, it's just the new pants ;)

Comment: @Krumia: Better still, not wider, but [fluid](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277229/157247).

Comment: The width of `<div id="content">` was increased from 980 to 1000px.

Answer (score 11):

Please change the ***interesting/favorite tags question background to rgba(255, 235, 162, 0.7)*** instead of rgba(255, 245, 222, 0.7)

This orangeish color is way better.

- it's way easier to read
- it's more exciting color (hence **favorite tag question**!!)
- the pinkish current color is just awful too be honest, hard to read, favorite tag questions should be ***easier*** to read then normal questions, not harder!
- when I think of SO, I think of the color orange, orange is in the logo!

See how much better this looks below with rgba(255,235,162,0.7)! :

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Apologies if this has already been brought up, but the lack of monospace font when composing something really annoys me. Using italics (like *this* or *this*) just doesn't look right:

> [image]

It actually kind of brings back memories of phpBB forums:

[image]

Which is not a good thing to make me remember. So *please* bring back the monospace font in composing areas. I really like most of the other changes, nice work!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277296

Answer (score 10):

On the answer editor clicking on the "Markdown Editing Help" button, the spacing between the yellow bar and the text box is incorrect, cutting the text on the first line.

Chrome 38.0.2125.122, OSX 10.10.1

[image]

Answer (score 10):

My 4 cents.

- Lack of- or too dull hover effects on interactive elements.
- Links are hard to distinguish or even indistinguishable from normal text. It was already an issue with old SO - design change should be made in opposite direction.
- Fonts of elements indicating important actions (e.g. *Post Answer*, *Ask Question* buttons) should be bold, like they were before. Current look highlights less important things with bold font (like "**Send me new responses to my posts via email**" under this box).
- New logo looks sad and hesitant.

  [image: New logo]

  Brave old one as posted by @msrd0.

  [image: Old logo]

Comment: Really dislike the changed logo. Such a petty thing, but just wanted to register my complaint. It's too small, suffers from bad aliasing, and now has a stack that wanders off at some quirky angle and looks unfinished.

Answer (score 10):

[image: The buttons are too bright]

The buttons in the reivew queues are too bright. You can hardly read the text. If the button is greyed out (more like "blued out" in this case) it's nearly impossible to tell, what the text is supposed to say without squinting.

Answer (score 10):

Why does editing a comment look so different from the actual comment. I'd like it to at least use the same font (incl. size).

> [image: edit]

> [image: comment]

Answer (score 9):

It's too easy to mis-click the upvote arrow. If you click just slightly above the actual arrow you're hitting some white space...

[image]

Although I am not sure this is something *new* but I have never really noticed that before.

Answer (score 9):

Am I the only one who has difficulty reading Helvetica Neue at font size 15?

This is the 50th answer, but the first one (that I've found having read through the other 49) bringing up the current main question/answer font (which has been the same for a while I assume). If you are going to do a redesign, my main concern would be to replace this as the first font (obviously I can do things on my end to make sure I never see it, but this isn't just about me).

I feel like maybe I am going insane because nobody else has brought this up, at least here in this question. To explain, let me repost some sentences that gave me headaches from the first few answers here. In the second sentence of each example listed below, I've typed lowercase L instead of I:

MSO's got its business suit and tie on

MSO's got lts buslness sult and tle on

It looks like normal text unless you've visited it.

lt looks llke normal text unless you've vlslted lt.

(There are some screenshots further down if you have a different screen/browser than mine.)

I can barely tell the difference between these sentences if I look close - lowercase i looks just like lowercase l.

(On top of this the font in general looks like everything is written in bold, but that's not a big issue for me).

I've had this problem before with uppercase I and lowercase l before, like reading Kim Jong Il as Kim Jong the 2nd (as a U.S. president once read it, I'm assuming they printed his script in Arial or something). But never with lowercase i. I can't see the dot.

I wondered if maybe it was Google Chrome, but it is even worse in Firefox. I'll post some actual screenshots here in case other people aren't seeing this like I am on their screens:

Chrome Helvetica Neue Screenshot 1: [image: Chrome Helvetica Neue Screenshot 1]

Chrome Helvetica Neue Screenshot 2: [image: Chrome Helvetica Neue Screenshot 2]

Firefox Helvetica Neue Screenshot 1: [image: Firefox Helvetica Neue Screenshot 1]

Granted, I have problems in general with the entire Internet being obsessed with whitespace!!! when I have 30ish eye floaters swimming across my vision, but this is the worst readability issue I've come across in a long time.

To delve into this a bit deeper, I looked at what is actually being rendered by blowing up the 2nd Chrome screenshot:

[image: Chrome Screenshot Enlarged]

There's a pixel (or a few pixels maybe) almost as black as the dot in the i connecting the dot and the main portion of the i, so I guess it isn't just my eyes.

Anyway, if nobody else has this problem it does at least make for hilarious reading on my end.

Comment: I think the font looks alright on the main page, but the font size used for questions makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 8):

It's nice, though I feel that the border on the required and moderator tags should be wider.  And, the text area really needs to be monospace again.

Current tag appearances:

```html
<head>
  <link href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/all.css?v=807be6a0d832" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/full.en.js?v=a587329010b1" async=""></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tags-legend">

    <b>Legend</b>
    <span>
      <a title="this is a moderator tag; it can only be added to a question by a ♦ moderator" class="post-tag moderator-tag">moderator-only-tag</a>
    </span>
    <span>
       <a title="this is a required tag; every new question must have at least one required tag" class="post-tag required-tag">required-tag</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a title="this is a standard tag; every question must have at least one tag" class="post-tag">tag</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a title="show all tag synonyms" class="tag-synonym-link" href="/tags/synonyms">tag synonyms</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

> [image: Actual tag borders: Currently width of 1px]

With border size increased to 2 pixels:

```css
.moderator-tag {
  border-width: 2px !important;
}
.required-tag {
  border-width: 2px !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/all.css?v=807be6a0d832" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/full.en.js?v=a587329010b1" async=""></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tags-legend">

    <b>Legend</b>
    <span>
      <a title="this is a moderator tag; it can only be added to a question by a ♦ moderator" class="post-tag moderator-tag">moderator-only-tag</a>
    </span>
    <span>
       <a title="this is a required tag; every new question must have at least one required tag" class="post-tag required-tag">required-tag</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a title="this is a standard tag; every question must have at least one tag" class="post-tag">tag</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a title="show all tag synonyms" class="tag-synonym-link" href="/tags/synonyms">tag synonyms</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

> [image: Borders of 2px]

Answer (score 8):

At the flag summary, the indicator for an active flag looks like this:

[image: Indicator for active flag]

The grey-brown foreground is not very readable on the orange background. Can the foreground please get another color?

Answer (score 8):

The "This question has been deleted - no more answers will be accepted." banner looks out of place:

[image]

A little styling there (maybe center the text vertically) would really help.

Comment: They probably forgot to style it because the slidey messages aren't supposed to exist anymore. They should just get rid of that and implement a better alert.

Answer (score 8):

**BUG:**

The tags when using inline tag editor have poor margins:

[image: cramped]

Currently, `.tag-editor .post-tag` has `margin: 6px 3px 0 3px;`. It would look better with `margin: 3px;`. The parent `.tag-editor`, which appears to be styled via js, needs `height: 33px;` rather than `height: 30px;`. That looks like this:

[image: fixed]

Answer (score 8):

Selecting 'ignored tags as grayed' results in far too low of contrast.

[image]

Even though I want to (semi) ignore them, I *do* want to be able to read them. The low-low-low contrast forces the eye to linger on them in order to make it out.  The result is eye strain, headaches, and twice now (so far), ocular migraines (not kidding one bit).  I havent had one in 2 years until this change.

---

Also, and this may already be in this long, long list of gripes, but the "actions" menu on posts doesnt look like a menu:

> [image]

The spacing makes it look like a string of words; and the choice of grey implies Disabled. **I** know it is a menu, but a new user may not and we already have enough trouble getting with new users being able to easily edit their posts.

The grey did cause me a moment of pause when I saw it in a review queue.

Comment: On the other hand, answers with score -3 are not grayed as they used to be ([for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27995960/960757)).

Comment: I had not noticed that, but I have had to curtail the time spent on SO as a result of the changes and make that time count.  So no time to browse The Wonderfullness of It All.

Comment: I've "fixed" this by setting `opacity: 0.5` for `.question-summary.tagged-ignored`. It still grays out the question, but it's slightly more readable.

Answer (score 7):

`<H3>` doesn't look like a subtitle anymore.  Well, it sorta does, but it's *very* subtle.  Bold actually works better.

Compare:

> #### This is an H3 Title
>
> Here is some text.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

With:

> **This is a Bolded Line**
>
> Here is some text.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

This broke some of the FAQ posts; I had to go back and fix them.  Examples:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271543

Comment: Already reported http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277370/1400768

Answer (score 6):

Can this font be made to match the rest of the site?

[image]

It doesn't seem to have changed - I don't think it matched anything before, and still doesn't seem to now.

Answer (score 6):

Something (the new font?) makes my previously 3 line paragraphs become 4 line ugly paragraphs.

I sometimes carefully craft them and now they are all broken. Applies to everyone's answer, it's just few people actually revisit them and continously remember the old readability so they don't take notice.

---

**[update 1]** I saw font-size was `107%`, `13.7px` for me. Now `15px`. *Setting it back seems to fix this.*

Comment: came here from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283714/ (2015 January, SO change)

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I assume syntax highlighting was changed along with the overall design. I'm not a big fan of green html tags:

[image]

<sub>Source: [DOM 'disabled' property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23701672/621962).</sub>

The relevant style:

```
.tag {
    color: #4c9067;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is this scheme borrowed from a popular editor?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's just the calibration of my monitor, but deleted answers are too pink for my liking... If anything it makes it look like the deleted answer is more important than the other answers.

> [image: Current]

Comment: I rather like the different shade, but I try to calibrate all my monitors perfectly, and we can't expect everyone to do that. Nice observation.

Answer (score 5):

The vertical margins between `li > p` and `li` in nested lists have never really been consistent on any site where I am active, which has been one of my greatest pet peeves when writing nested lists. Could this get a fix?

- Margins are consistent if both the outer and inner list items are `li > p`, as expected:

  - Item
  - Item
- Item
- Margins are wonky towards the bottom if the inner list items are not `li > p` and the only workaround is to give all the inner items paragraphs, even if the inner items are single lines:

  - Item
  - Item
- Item

This happens because `p` and `li` (well, `:matches(.post-text, .wmd-preview) :matches(ul, ol) li` anyway) have only bottom margins defined, and not top margins. I suspect this is for a good reason, so I won't ask for top margins. However, it should be as simple as either making the bottom margins equal or, possibly, making only `li > p` bottom margins the same as `li`.

Answer (score 5):

I have a small bug that I think is one, Forwarded here by JasonC, from another thread: [Google Chrome shows broken text on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277684/google-chrome-shows-broken-text-on-stack-overflow)

**My Specs:**

- Running Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 m
- Windows 8.1
- I have NO extra fonts installed and browsing with Zoom 100%
  (Original)

**The Bug:**
The overlapping of gray background over the @ symbol is a small spacing overlapping bug right? Picture:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I can also confirm that on 39.0.2171.65 m on Windows 7, the gray background behind the username extends above the descender on the previous line. My "@" does not hang as low as in this picture, but the gray square overlaps my "g" by one pixel in comments. I didn't notice this before, not sure if it is related to new font tweaks.

Answer (score 5):

The icon on this screenshot is clearly not in high DPI, so it looks blurry on Retina™ displays, for example. (Compare to the nearby text)
[image: screenshot]

(I'm using Firefox on OS X 10.10)

Comment: Would you mind uploading the screenshot to imgur using the image upload tool in the editor?

Comment: @nhahtdh Done (2 more to go...)

Comment: That icon comes from a [massive sprite sheet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=d1fa29230270b12410ec5ae487182a5c) that contains all the icons for the entire network. I don't think you'll see that fixed any time soon, nor does it have anything to do with this new design.

Comment: It looks blurry on *all* high-resolution displays, not just Apple devices/computers.

Comment: @cybermonkey yes, of course! that's why I wrote "for example".

Comment: @animuson http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=d1fa29230270b12410ec5ae487182a5c

Answer (score 5):

Just thought I'd mention the broken tags when editing a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/277834/edit):

[image]

*Also the misaligned 'Edit Summary' box, however this may have been intentional.*

Comment: I [reported this separately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277517/the-tags-are-disappearing-in-the-tag-box-again-even-worse-than-last-time) because it's not specific to this design, just much more prevalent.

Comment: @animuson Interesting, I haven't seen this happen before.

Answer (score 5):

[status-verified](/questions/tagged/status-verified)
[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Help" icon of the questions/answers editor is middle-outside the editor on Firefox 35.0 (Mac OS X 10.10.1).

[image]

Good work anyway, I really enjoy the new color highlighting :-).

Comment: It's back again (on the wrong place). Firefox 36.0.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The black top border on the sort menu-items is too dark and noticeable.

Please change it to the same color as the left/right borders. (*or maybe just a tad darker*)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Upvote/downvote stats in Linked/Related questions are a clutter. There has got to be a better way of displaying this.

An idea (ignore the code. Just run the code snippet):

```css
* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<table style="width: 200px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="color:green;">23</span><br/><span style="color:red">4</span>
    </td>
    <td>How to foo the bar in Foobaz?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="color:green;">4</span><br/><span style="color:red">-1</span>
    </td>
    <td>How to foo the bar?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="color:green;">1k+</span><br/><span style="color:red">11</span>
    </td>
    <td>How to foo the bar in Foobaz while having a fubar?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="color:green;">8</span>
    </td>
    <td>How to foo the bar?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Please make "meta" part of the logo text same size as the rest of the text. Much like Stack Overflow Careers' logo.

Or, if you really want to have smaller text, make it a superscript.

(Ignore the font weights and colors. I hope you get the idea.)

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 32px;"><span style="color:gray">stack</span><span style="font-weight: bold">overflow</span><span style="color: red">meta</span></p>

<p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 32px;"><span style="color:gray">stack</span><span style="font-weight: bold">overflow</span><sup><span style="color: red">meta</span></sup></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The old font is more readable to me, maybe the font used could be changed?
Readability in the buttons, is also much better in old version.

I always think that less is more, so when you start adding unnecessary stuff to a page it becomes bloated. The old one is perfect, so why changing?

I think if you just create a pool and let everyone vote if the design should change or not, most people will vote against it. Most people don't like changes when it comes to websites, because they are used to it already.

My request, please don't change.

Comment: The new design is ok right now, it needs some fixes as the many answers show. Changes are not bad, especially when we can make those changes better incrementally.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau they are bad when it hurts to try to read the new style

Answer (score 3):

Today, I'm trying to edit my existing tags, thus what is show me in "edit mode"
[image]

Each favourite tags with two delete buttons, and yes, I am able to remove it by clicking any of the delete buttons.

P.S. When I refreshed the page it will changed to normal, but after sometime when I back, it'll have the same look as above.

Answer (score 3):

Kerning seems off in the normal font in questions / answers. Not sure if it's the font, the css, or my browser (Chrome, Windows 7). Here's a few examples I found in the question and answers on this post.

the `c` and `o` in "icons"

[image]

between the `c` and `k` in "luck":

[image]

Comment: On mac Safari, that bottom part doesn't show the issue with kerning. http://i.stack.imgur.com/liUMh.png

Comment: @MichaelT font rendering on Macs is completely different than Windows, see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html. I can duplicate the problem on Windows 7 and Chrome. I also see it in IE10 but it's less severe.

Answer (score 3):

I like the overall look of the new site, however one thing which is instantly causing an issue is that the background colour for questions "i might be interested in" is so faint that you can't instantly distinguish between them and the ones not interested in.

I'm talking about this:

[image]

It used to be so obvious which questions fell under the tags I've selected, now it's very difficult to see.

Taking the opacity off of the background will do it! or using the colour from "hot topics" :-)

Answer (score 3):

The new style became "flat", like Android 5.0.

For instance the star button lost its' 3rd dimension. At the first look it looks like a piece of paper, but I am a fan of more 3d look despite that now clean, flat fashion becomes more popular.

The font itself is probably better in terms if readability.

Comment: The font sucks, at least the one I'm seeing a lot.  It's a sanserif font with very little spacing between the letters and it has the same readability problem as ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 3):

The different coloring of visited vs non-visited links in the footer is unnecessarily conspicuous.

[image: footer]

1. Turning visited links into gray gives the impression that you're done with the items. In turn, the remaining red links keep signaling "click me!" as if they are todo items, which they are not.
2. The footer is there for navigation. As users are going to click through the navigation items many times whenever they need to do so, whether or not they visited the link before isn't vital information.

I suggest toning down the difference in a way similar to how it's done in the Beta theme: adjust the lightness/saturation while keeping the same hue.

[image: Beta theme]

Answer (score 3):

What happend on the "User Profiles"?

[image]

Comment: yes this is a bug we're fixing

Answer (score 2):

On my iPad, there isn't enough padding on the sides, even in landscape mode.

The logo, title, votes, pagination, answer box, answer button, basically everything left-aligned is too far to the left.

Also, the search bar overflows the top bar.

Edit: just saw https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277223/3187556  reporting the left padding issue. Well, i still have the search bar report.

Answer (score 2):

The top of the tabs seem a little close to the about me box on profiles:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

The left section contains Home, Questions, Tags and Users

IMHO it seems to take up a lot of screen space especially if the post spans across multiple pages, it is blank white space which could be better served.

As a result of this the the actual content is cramped and now the similar questions and the right section also is fighting for this space.

Roughly around 1/6th of the width (left portion) is just white space, would be better to keep it on top like previously.

Note: I am no design expert, this is just a feedback as a user, thanks

[image: Left side bar takes up a lot of space]

Comment: Yes, thank you! It is cramping up good content. This could have been a drop down. When did we ever have an issue with "Questions", "Tags"?

Answer (score 1):

The user who a bounty was awarded to is too large.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider reducing the `padding` and `margin` on tags (particularly the vertical padding).  The current settings mean that tags increase the line-height unnecessarily.  Some new settings might be:

```
.post-tags {
    padding:.1em .4em;
    margin:1px 2px 2px 0;
}
```

The difference is shown below (current on left, proposed on right):

[image: Two text samples, one with current settings for tag padding and margins and the other with proposed changes.]

Comment: Your proposal looks ugly and it doesn't strike you right away that it is a tag. Either way, it is not a new thing introduced by the recent change - the design for display of tag in post body has been like this for at least 2-3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Did something change with how the SO icons are presented or linked, other than the SVG upgrade mentioned?  Basically right now none of the SO icons are coming through; my topbar is solid black except for the plain text and my gravatar image.  The comment flags on this post don't show, unless I'm not able to see them anyway.

The reason for this I'm pretty sure is because of my company's web blocking firewall software, so I don't think it's really an SO problem.  But is there anything I can point to in having them allow that could be preventing the sprites from loading or something?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this is a message I get in Chrome Dev Tools:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=7966d6d82b78".`

Comment: I'm looking through any old missed reports - I can't repro this though, are you still seeing the issue? If so which OS/Chrome version?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I actually created a question with more details (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281337/278763), but it looks like it's probably my corporate firewall blocking something.  I'm not sure yet what to request of our admins to change, but that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile device (iPhone 6) the SO and navigation icon is kind a broken...[image] (not sure if I toggle the nav or reload the page)

Comment: How is it broken?

Comment: @Jin it shows an icon and half a icon.. is that not broken?

Answer (score 0):

When I search for a bunch of tags, now they appear at the top of the page in a really big font.

I tried to find a screenshot for the older design, but I'm unable to. I remember that the tags were displayed on the side, without this huuuuge title.

I think this help a lot with the clarity for shorter queries, but there could be a limit. E.g. If the header would take >50% of the screen, either summarize the search, use a smaller font, revert to the old side option, ...

You should be able to see it for yourself by visiting the [same link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform%20or%20google-cloud-platform%20or%20google-bigquery%20or%20google-cloud-dataflow%20or%20google-cloud-datalab%20or%20google-cloud-dataprep%20or%20google-cloud-dataproc%20or%20google-cloud-pubsub%20or%20google-hadoop%20or%20google-prediction%20or%20google-translate%20or%20google-translation-api%20or%20google-data-studio%20or%20google-genomics%20or%20google-cloud-ml%20or%20google-cloud-nl%20or%20google-cloud-speech%20or%20video-intelligence-api%20or%20google-cloud-vision%20or%20gcsfuse%20or%20google-cloud-bigtable%20or%20google-cloud-datastore%20or%20google-cloud-spanner%20or%20google-cloud-sql%20or%20google-cloud-storage%20or%20gsutil%20or%20app-engine-flexible%20or%20appengine-gradle-plugin%20or%20google-cloud-datastore%20or%20google-app-engine%20or%20gcloud%20or%20gcloud-intellij%20or%20gcloud-java%20or%20gcloud-node%20or%20gcloud-python%20or%20google-cloud-dotnet%20or%20google-cloud-eclipse%20or%20google-cloud-intellij%20or%20google-cloud-powershell%20or%20google-cloud-sdk%20or%20google-cloud-source-repos%20or%20google-cloud-visualstudio%20or%20google-plugin-eclipse%20or%20google-cloud-endpoints%20or%20google-cloud-functions%20or%20google-deployment-manager%20or%20appengine-maven-plugin%20or%20google-eclipse-plugin%20or%20maven-gae-plugin%20or%20gke).

[image: search for multiple tags]

Comment: You just answered a 3 years old questions ^ ^

Comment: @Adam Damn, I just searched in meta for "new stack overflow design", this feedback showed, and I don't even know why I thought it was related... This will show me to look at the details! Thanks for the heads-up, I'll try to hone my searching skills and look for the relevant post.

Comment: Funny how a lot of the same complaints come up though... People are really sensitive to white space :).

Comment: In case someone comes here, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness/311173#311173) looks to be the proper thread.

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369366/2960971 on meta.SO is directly about it (and not locked so you can actually respond/vote).

Comment: @IncredibleHat True! I don't know what's going on with my searching skills. I think I need a vacation...

Comment: Its ok, I didn't find that either when I was looking for other people annoyed by the header change. I ended up 'fixing' it using adblockplus (in chrome) and simply blocking that specific h1 element. Others fixed it in firefox with a css override. Not sure how to fix it in Edge, or Opera.

Answer (score -6):

The older questions have 'ask' should also tell months along with years ago, For e.g see this screenshot below[image]:

Questions was asked in Dec 2010. So it is 3 years and 11 months old. And asked is saying 3 years ago. It should say 3 years 11 months ago!

Thanks

Comment: But how is it related to design update?

Comment: Also, does this really matter that much? It is close enough to the real date.

Comment: it would have been close to real date if it said 4 years ago. As it is 3 years and 11 months old. so saying 3 years old is not close to real date.

Comment: Hard to get ones shorts in a twist about this issue.

Answer (score -7):

Make the links blue with a line under them. Visited links can be purple.

This is a developer site so those are the correct colors for it.

Even more awesome would be to remove the colors from everything and use the system colors.

If you are still coding in a text editor with a white background you simply haven't done enough of it. Switching from a dark editor to a stack overflow page is like someone is pointing a spotlight in your face. What is up with that? Am I being interrogated here? lol

The idea behind the bright white is to render the rest of the room invisible to the user, this is not something we need here. There are no products to be sold.

System fonts, system colors and system buttons. Make a nice design using padding, lines and icons but leave the rest the way the visitor likes it. If people don't have the system colors configured it looks precisely the way it looks now. The shocking reality is that developers who did configure it know what they like better than any design team. A truly terrifying idea I know, sorry to be the one to bring the bad news. lol

I know you have your own ideas about design but surely the fact I know what you like better than you is irrefutable at this point. hhahaha

good luck & keep up the good work!

Answer (score -9):

If **Header is fixed** then it will be good, because if some comments are posted we will note be aware.