# Why comment box margin is different on this site?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm not sure I've to ask this or not, but if its not a bug then?

I found that, comment box margin are different on meta.stackoverflow.com then few other sites which I checked.

Meta Comment box:
[image]

StackOverflow Comment box:
[image]

Ask Different Comment box:
[image]

SuperUser Comment box:
[image]

There's some left (may be 5) margin in meta comment box.

Comment: See [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update)

Answer (score 5):

MSO was redesigned, that is the reason behind the different look.

Please leave your feedback on the announcement: [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update?cb=1)