# Numbers wrapping when linked/related questions have >99 votes

Tags: bug, design

The new design is great, but the linked/related questions are bugging:

[image: Imgur]

---

[Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277200/2479481)

Comment: This bug has actually already been mentioned on the featured page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277208/2555451

Comment: That is true @iCodez but this is how they requested issues with the design to be raised.