# SVG update breaks scaling in Opera 12.16 on Linux

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, opera

As requested in [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update):

The SVG update completely breaks the Opera experience when zoom <>  100%

I might not be the only one using Opera, but am I the only one who zooms to get readable fonts on his high-DPI screen...?

Information:

- **Version** https://i.stack.imgur.com/5998J.png Opera 12.16 Build 1860 on Linux 64
- **Linux** Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- I typically zoom between 120%-180% in case that matters

> - [image]

---

> - [image]

---

> - [image]

---

> - [image]

Comment: I don't experience any problems when zooming in on Opera. What version are you using? P.S. Behavior not seen on any other browsers either.

Comment: @animuson I know it's opera specific. Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16. Here's a gif that shows how resizing is involved: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ukWo3.gif

Comment: I can confirm the problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3gL.png (Opera 12.17 on 64-bit Windows, Presto/2.12.388"). However, it is still usable, for example at a zoom level of 250% on the screen I am using.

Comment: What zoom level are you using?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I vary the zoom level quite a bit, let's say from. I'd say my working range would be 100%-180%. As [the gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ukWo3.gif) is intended to show, things go off balance pretty soon as one starts changing the zoom level.

Comment: People still use Opera? I thought after they sold out to webkit that they had effectively died. Now they implement a substandard edition of webkit that cannot handle SVGs correctly `:/` Edit: You are seeing it since you are using a very old edition of Opera, try upgrading

Comment: Just so we're all clear. OP is using Opera 12.16. It's the almost latest and greatest. Some misunderstanding has arisen due to the useragent's format. However, they're not running an ancient version. It's new. It's fresh. It's Norwegian.

Comment: @Sammaye As long as the linux version keeps on being awesome with the keyboard, I'll keep using it. (When that changes, I'd probably go Firefox with something like Pentadactyl (?))

Comment: Zoom levels other than 100% are *not supported*.

Comment: Not sure version 12 is still supported beyond security critical fixes, as that is the old (and far better) Presto based version of Opera, rather than the current Chrome clone.

Comment: I think i may have accidentally encountered the Presto  build on windows. It ducks  so badly that i have moved to chrome in windows

Comment: Presto is the older (12.17 and earlier) versions. 15 onwards are the Chrome clones.

Comment: I can confirm this on Windows7 and Opera 12.17

Comment: The early WebKit based versions of Opera were so bad that I kept using v12 for quite a while, but they've added many features to it now. Basically it's as fast and compatible as Chrome, but it's much more than a Chrome clone. Some v12 features are probably still missing and certain things are different, but overall I'm pretty pleased. And it gets better with each version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an issue with Stack Exchange, but with your browser, and should be reported to Opera.

When you zoom into the page, you also have to zoom the SVG image to make it larger. Doing so, you also have to translate the background positions to account for the new location of the piece of the image which was being shown in the box. Opera is clearly failing to do the second part of this task, and what you're seeing is the zoomed/enlarged image at the same coordinates where the unzoomed image used to be located.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just wanted you to know that this is happening. Historically, Opera has been a frontrunner in SVG renedering. So I didn't want to assume Opera was the only browser that didn't implement a particular quirk that enabled other browsers to get the right behaviour. I trust you have checked this (or know the stuff so well that you don't need to :)), so I can report with Opera.

Comment: Opera has switched to WebKit with Opera 15. It's unlikely they will do anything and release a 12.x version, if reported…

Comment: @sehe: At least there are [issues with zooming in other browsers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280010/1048572) as well :-)