# Stack Overflow logo cropped at 90% in chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, images, logo

The SO logo is being slightly cropped at 90% zoom in Chrome.

Its fine above and below 90% zoom but specifically 90% zoom it is cropped.

**75% Zoom**

[image]

**90% Zoom**

[image]

**100% Zoom**

[image]

Comment: Cropped at 90% of what?

Comment: 90% zoom in Google chrome, added zoom for clarification

Comment: The site will get a new SVG logo whenever the new design gets pushed there, so technically this will be completed at *some point* in the future.

Comment: There we have it! was just an observation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see strange artifacts when zooming in/out, that's to be expected.

The sites are designed for 100% zoom level.

Comment: They work at every other zoom level except 90%

Comment: Happy coincidence then. We don't and never did support zooming. In particular for a minor visual issue that has no other impact whatsoever.

Comment: Wow. I would probably never contribute anything /at all/ on SO if zooming didn't reasonably work. Not everyone has perfect eyesight. And the SVG design update did break the scaling (badly) on my browser. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277345/svg-update-breaks-scaling-in-opera-12-16-on-linux - I know know - "that's too bad. Run at 100% or use the blessed browsers". But the story "We don't support zooming" is vastly oversimplified. If it hadn't worked "reasonably", you would have gotten some response!

Comment: @sehe - this bug report is about the logo being cropped, not about any functionality of the site. We don't care about purely cosmetic bugs that are caused by zooming in/out.

Comment: @sehe - I am not trying to downplay the issue you are having - I took a look at the linked bug report and unfortunately the answer I have for that one is that you are using an unsupported browser (not really supported by its maker anymore) - if it were an _easy_ fix for us, we would do it, but a buggy browser that will not see updates is a different story.

Comment: Ok. I was just responding to the wording that you did use in this answer though. The was not a lot of room for such nuance there ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really an issue at all. Web developers rarely cater for zoom levels within browsers as it's almost always a pointless endeavour. In an ideal world, the 100% default zoom level would give no reason for anyone to zoom in or out in the first place.

Equally, the person in control of the zoom on their browser is the user themselves, not the web developer. Sure, you could add in some hacky CSS to make 90% zoom level more appealing, but if you're going to do this then you're also going to want to do it for 80%, 70% and 60%, and you'd quickly get to a point where it would become silly to attempt to "fix" this.

If you're going to start posting issues caused by zooming in or out, then you'd have a field day on the [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page.

Comment: They work at every other zoom level except 90%

Comment: @Matt looks like it does it on 110% as well. Heck, I can barely even see the logo if I zoom out to 25%.

Comment: "*In an ideal world, the 100% default zoom level would give no reason for anyone to zoom in or out in the first place*" Seriously? In an ideal world, we all have perfect vision and we'd be able to keep the screen at a constant distance from our eyes.

Comment: "web developers rarely cater for zoom levels within browsers" - Speak for yourself, please. I test all of my web products using various zoom levels and font sizes even before it goes to QA. Not everyone has perfect vision.