# UI issues with privilege tracking bar

Tags: bug, design

When I zoom on the privilege tracking bar, the left of it escapes the edges and the edges on the right look blocky and not rounded as the outer edges would suggest.

[image: privilege tracking bar with bad UI]

Comment: When you say zoom do you mean zooming the full page or zooming in on a screen shot?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am zooming the full page.

Comment: looks like this is a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280010/stack-overflow-logo-cropped-at-90-in-chrome) then.  **tl;dr** SO only supports 100% zoom.

Comment: I am zooming in Safari which zooms like a mobile device on macOS, so no, that is **definitely** not a dupe.