# Talent and Teams ads gets cut off in developer survey results page

Tags: bug, survey

When reading this year's developer survey results, I noticed that even when scrolling to the very bottom, the ad for Stack Overflow Talent was only half showing and the ad for Stack Overflow Teams was completely hidden unless I zoomed out.

[image: screenshot of developer survey results page showing cut off ad]

I'm using Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 on a 1920 x 1080 screen with 150% size (Windows 10).

Comment: [Zooming is not supported,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280013/7795130) [neither in, nor out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/363946).

Comment: However I can recreate this issue at 100% zoom. I'm using Firefox version 66.0.2 (64-bit) for Windows 10, with a 1920 x 1080 screen as well. So ignoring the 150% size, it still has an issue at 100% zoom.

Comment: Here's a direct link for anyone who wants to see if they recreate: [Developer Survey Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019)

Comment: @DavyM When I say 150% I'm talking about the setting in Windows that adjusts the size of everything, including apps, not the zoom in Chrome. I can only see the Teams ad if I zoom out in Chrome.