# The tags are disappearing in the tag box again, even worse than last time!

Tags: bug, tags, design

[This bug was declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197565/the-case-of-the-tags-that-werent-there-because-they-were-scared-of-my-burninati) some time ago. With the new design, it has returned and gotten **even worse**. At certain lengths while you're typing, the tags will jump off to the left:

> [image: Tags off side]

Out of the last five questions where I edited tags, they have jumped clear to the left **three times**. I think I've encountered the previous bug *once* in all my time I've used Stack Overflow. The fact that the new design has popped it up three times *already* (in the span of 15 minutes) is very concerning and I think this bug warrants more interest in order to be fixed.

**Please make it stop!!!**

---

Also, is it me, or did the tag dropdown thing get *way* smaller and more compressed? Possibly related?

> [image: Tag dropdown]

Comment: **Note:** Even though this is much more prevalent on the new Meta design, I didn't tag it with [meta-tag:meta] because it *can* occur on the current Stack Overflow theme - it's just extremely rare.