# Bad formatting on meta website on IE11

Tags: bug, internet-explorer

Today, while posting [one bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283337/after-editing-a-comment-the-prompt-stuck-on-textarea-after-pressing-enter), I found another bug!

The meta website is all pulled to the right.

An image is worth more than 1000 words:

[image: Printscreen on this website]

One more to show the tags (doesn't happen on editing):

[image: Showing the tags]

And now, on [another website](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

[image: Printscreen on meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com]

My UA String is the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Translation: Windows 8.1 Pro 64bits running IE11 32bits (default) with most of settings on default, except the Hardware Acceleration and Autocorrect where disabled.

This happens everywhere, including in the questions!

I have no idea what might be causing this. Maybe a `margin`?

Comment: @animuson If that is the problem, why the other meta sites are perfect?

Comment: Because MSO uses its own design which is still being develoled before it gets pushed out to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @animuson 'own design'? But there are no differences... And what about the input with the tags?

Comment: Yes, MSO currently uses its own design which is not used anywhere else on the network. There may be similarities, but it is a completely different stylesheet.

Comment: @animuson Restricting the bug to the badly formated tag input would mark this as a different question, making it "recoverable"?

Comment: Also: [The tags are disappearing in the tag box again, even worse than last time!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277517/the-tags-are-disappearing-in-the-tag-box-again-even-worse-than-last-time)

Comment: @animuson What about this issue: http://i60.tinypic.com/2803zf6.png ? Was it reported? The `X` button is.... well, almost eaten up and barely clickable.

Comment: I'm... not completely sure what that X is even supposed to be for. So probably not.

Comment: The `X` is to delete the text that I'm introducing. And it isn't a "valid bug", since it is somewhat related to the width of the box. It's an IE10+ feature, introduced in Windows 8. That is to help users on touchscreens to delete the text at once, instead of deleting char by char in a screen keyboard. (I've checked on Opera and the `X` isn't there). If appropriate, please, delete the question since there is nothing new here. Otherwise, you may post the "bug" found in a new question with your name.