# Colors in comment characters remaining seem off

Tags: bug, design

With the new design, the colors for the "Characters remaining" text when posting a comment have the following progression:

- Grey
- Brown
- Orange
- Black (???)

I would expect the final color to be red, or a brighter orange like on the main site.

Comment: But then the colors wouldn't be a tribute to [GBOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Battle_of_the_Bands) :(

Comment: @iCodez I could use different shades if it would make you feel better :) It would be funny if that was the intention of the developers...

Comment: The comment "characters remaining" color scheme on MSE is similarly upside-down. The final color is black.

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update?cb=1

Comment: @nhahtdh That post said to post any bugs as a question tagged [meta-tag:design] and [meta-tag:bug]. Which is what I have done here. I could edit my existing answer over there, but its not guaranteed to be seen. Additionally, my comments there were observations/comments, this is an actual bug in my opinion.

Comment: The comment vote counts follow this [same weird color pattern](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277645/616460). I wonder if they use the same palette / logic?

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be:

- Grey until 15
- Yellow at 320
- Red at 600

Comment: Wasn't it originally percentage-based?  I'd think it would make more sense to have it percentage based.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Hm… It'd be better in the middle, but exactly home many characters are required is useful near 15 and 600.

Comment: Red is not good. Usually it is associated with something bad.

Comment: @NO_NAME … such as a serious problem with the post that would make the server reject it.

Comment: @bjb568 Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

It should probably transition to red only after you pass the character count limit.

Comment: I still wouldn't use black as the "You are getting close!" color.