# Google Chrome shows broken text on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, google-chrome

Just signed up and looking through posts.

Running Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 m

Here is a screenshot if wondering.

[image: Screenshot]

I have no extra fonts installed and browsing with Zoom 100% (Original)

Comment: @xtrman I can't reproduce this with 39.0.2171.65 m, Windows 7. Does it persist if you refresh the page?

Comment: @JasonC I am also running windows 8.1 if that changes anything. It doesn't persist constantly, but every other thread I view, it does that.

Comment: @xtrman Is that the only section of the site that does that, and does it happen on meta or any of the other SE sites?

Comment: @JasonC, I cant even see that line of text or that option on meta, not sure why...? But it happens on the regular stack overflow where people talk about programming languages. One more thing, the overlapping of gray background over the @ symbol is a regular thing right? Picture: http://i.imgur.com/bL5fP3f.png

Comment: @xtrman The reason you can't see it on meta is because I'm talking out of my ass, and the "Know somebody who can answer?" isn't actually on the metas. The overlap you see is not a *regular* thing but is likely a consequence of some unrelated recent design changes to meta, discussed at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update?cb=1. Jin has been messing with the comment font sizes recently. Good catch, and you should probably point it out as an answer on that thread (let me know if you don't feel like it; I will if you don't).

Comment: If you could inspect those elements and look for odd HTML and CSS around that area, it would go a long way in solving this problem. The screenshot doesn't really tell us anything if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: I asked the community team a while ago, but they replied that this is what you have got when using bleeding edge Chromium. Ever since, I could not use it and eventually switched back to Firefox. :( See the [following link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415678&q=code%20font&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) for details. I have been using Linux fwiw.