# Can we have the same black-and-white and retina-sized logo at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, design

The Meta logo is just perfect, it is elegant and not pixelated.

**Why the editors didn't change the normal Stack Overflow logo to this yet?**

Comment: Presumably, because they want [feedback on this new design](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277200/3717023) before pushing it to the main site.

Comment: Meta sites are frequently used to test new features and other new aspects of the site so the feature, when fully implemented, is fully vented by the community and the bugs are worked out.

Comment: First it's flattening everything now it's black and white. Designers are going back in time.

Comment: @simonzack The Meta site is always a greyscaled version of the main site. The new design on Stack Overflow will still feature the same orange theme we've come to love.

Comment: @animuson Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: Also lol "editors"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're still working out all the kinks of the new design [here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update?cb=1) first, before they push the new design to the main Stack Overflow. Note the design on Stack Overflow will not be black-and-white - it will still feature the same orange theme we've come to love. Meta is always a greyscaled version of the main site.

Patience - it will come.