# Markdown editor help icon is misplaced

Tags: bug, design, editor

Since the [new design update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update), the Markdown Editing Help icon (`wmd-help-button`) has been hanging awkwardly off the edge of the editor box:

[image: Screenshot]

Actually, it seems to have always been off the edge, it just wasn't quite so noticeable in the old design.

In any case, changing the `left: 639px` rule in the button's HTML `style` attribute to something like `left: 619px` fixes the issue, moving the button fully within the editor area.

Comment: Already reported (in one of the posts) in here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update