# When will design of SO finally updated? Will the other sites of trilogy be redesigned?

Tags: discussion, design

It has been already two weeks since the new design [was announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277200) on Meta Stack Overflow. When Stack Overflow will be redesigned?

Are there any plans to redesign two other sites ([Super User](http://superuser.com) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com))? It will be inconsistent for other trilogy sites to have another design.

Comment: You in any particular hurry?

Comment: @Martijn Of course not. Just interesting!

Comment: [Soon™](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Time).

Comment: @Compass Soon™? Are you serious?  Should be 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @nicael Depends on what scale of *Soon™* you're referring to. Valve Time Soon™ was 9 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Stack Overflow:

Hopefully not soon, as there are many bugs still present in the MSO template. I'm sure this is a low priority for the dev team.

### Super User and Server Fault:

Someday... but is there anything even wrong with them? Minor edits only if you ask me. (e.g., the width of the entire page)