# Why are the "apps" and "my logins" in red color in the profile page in meta?

Tags: support, meta, design, profile-page

I've noticed that the "apps" link and "my logins" link in the profile page in red color. Here is a screenshot showing it:

[image: screenshot]

This is seen only for the profile page on meta and not on the original site. Why are they in red color?

I clicked the "apps" link and it turned black but the "my logins" link remains red even after I've clicked it. Why?

Comment: You are a Cool Guy on your own, so why bother about the link colours? Actually red seems kind of cool to me :)

Comment: as for your edit - because you *don't actually visit* the my logins link. It opens a modal. If you manually put a hash after your profile url, and visit that, you will find that the link suddenly appears visited.

Comment: @J.Steen , Now I get it. And I tried what you said and now,none of the links are red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All** links start out red, but *visited* links are updated to show in dark grey instead.

From the Meta stylesheet:

```css
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #be1e2d;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #666;
}
```

The Meta styles have [recently been refreshed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update); the main site still uses the old styles while we iron out the bugs in the new stylesheet. On the main site all links in that header are fixed to one colour instead, black:

```css
.subheader a {
    color: #000;
}
```

The `my logins` is handled in javascript (it pops up a dialog and cancels the default action), so you never technically visit the link in your browser. If you right-clicked that URL, copied it, pasted it back into the browser, then you'd have visited it; the link only adds an empty hash fragment, so you can simply add `#` to your profile URL to make that link appear visited too.