# The re-design has borked the user flag history page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-history

It seems like the design changed very recently, and I'm pretty sure this is not how the flag history is supposed to look:

[image: screenshot]

All the vote counts are on displayed on a separate line and there is no background on the count itself unless there is an accepted answer :

[image: another screenshot]

Also, the "active" tag's text color could be better (white maybe?) and the "spam" tag looks wrong and is too large for the actual text.

I'm running Firefox 34.0.5 on Windows 7.

Comment: Confirmed, Jin has a fix incoming - thanks for the report!

Comment: Flag history layout in the new design was previously complained about here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277218

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom indeed... quite surprising actually, I would've expected all of that to be fixed before rolling out the new design to the main site.

Comment: Confirmed this is cross-browser.

Comment: @bjb568 ??? This should have been fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283878/question-titles-scores-misaligned-mismatched-size-in-flags-list It looks fine to me - the titles are larger now than they used to be, but the alignment with the vote scores is fine.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski "Also, the "active" tag's text color could be better (white maybe?) and the "spam" tag looks wrong and is too large for the actual text." isn't fixed.

Comment: @NickCraver The background overflow reported in [this duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283994/1928529) has not been fixed yet. ([Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/prBBLMb.png)). When taking the screenshot I noticed the time of flagging is shown for evertything I flagged, except for this spam flag.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 This has been fixed http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250735/241622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the spam flag markers (or at least, the *immediate* problem with them; their styling is kind of screwy in general) is that they have whitespace both inside and outside the marker span:

```html
            <div class="flag-spam-offensive">
flagged as <span class="bounty-indicator-tab flagbg bounty-fix"> spam </span>            <span class="flag-outcome Helpful">
                helpful
        </span>
```

<sup>(Yes, this is copy-pasted verbatim from the HTML source; the indentation really is that messed up.)</sup>

The reason this is a problem is that browsers will, of course, collapse all that consecutive whitespace into a single space.  But, apparently, they don't really agree on whether these spaces should be considered to be *inside* the span, or *outside* it.

My Firefox, at least, is (internally) consistent: it always collapses the spaces to the left, so that the space *before* the span is considered to be outside it, but the space *after* the span is considered to be inside it.  Alas, this makes the rendering look kind of ugly:

[image: Spam flag marker with display:inline, with spaces collapsed to the left]

This wasn't a problem in the old design, because the `bounty-indicator-tab` class was styled as `display: inline-block`.  However, the new design has `display: inline` instead, triggering all these whitespace issues.

(This is not unique to the flagging history page, by the way.  The same class name is also (ab)used in other places, like for the "flags remaining" indicator in the flagging dialog, which also exhibits funny spacing.)

The easiest way to fix this would be to simply **re-style these markers as inline-blocks again.**

If, for some reason, this is not desirable, an alternative solution would be to remove the spaces from the HTML inside them (or to replace them with `&nbsp;`, if the extra space is actually seen as desirable).  However, finding all the places in the SE codebase where this class (and its friends, like `mod-flag-indicator`) is used may take some digging.

---

In the mean time, I have added the `display: inline-block` style to the devel branch of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).  Here's what the markers look like with that fix:

[image: Spam flag marker, with display:inline-block]

If this fix doesn't cause any unexpected breakage (or unless the bug is properly fixed in the mean time), it will be part of the next stable SOUP release, v1.30.

**Update:** It turns out that this fix does break things in (at least) one place, namely in the user profile tabs (which this class presumably was originally intended for).  For now, I've addressed this simply by adding an extra rule to undo it there:

```css
body .bounty-indicator-tab { display: inline-block }
#tabs .bounty-indicator-tab { display: inline }
```

I've also limited this fix to SO and MSO for now; hopefully the bug will be properly fixed by the time the re-design is extended to other SE sites.

---

**Ps.** I did find yet another alternative solution, which prevents spaces inside the markers from being collapsed with those outside it, while still using `display: inline`.  It's kind of a hack, but for posterity, here it is:

```css
.bounty-indicator-tab:before, .bounty-indicator-tab:after { content: '\FEFF' }
```

Yes, that's a Unicode [Zero Width No-Break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm) (U+FEFF, a.k.a. Byte Order Mark).  Here's what the markers would look like with it:

[image: Spam flag marker, with U+FEFF CSS hack]

Comment: This has been fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250735/241622

Comment: Still broken in the flagging dialog, though. I should probably file a separate bug about that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Did you ever report the flag dialog bug?