# Question titles & scores misaligned/mismatched size in flags list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is pretty minor and not likely to bother a lot of people, but in the `/users/flag-summary` listing ("Helpful flags" as linked from your profile), either the question titles are a little too large, or the vote scores to the left of them are a little too small because they're appearing sort of as a "superscript" rather than inline.

Not a big deal, but visually a little difficult to parse except for those highlighted green as accepted answers.  It's especially pronounced when a title breaks over multiple lines.

[image: Screenshot of misaligned titles/counts]

For what it's worth, I'm seeing this in the newest Firefox & Chrome on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have pushed a fix for this. It will be on live after the next production build.