# Squished lines in review history

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

Related: [Question titles & scores misaligned/mismatched size in flags list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283878/question-titles-scores-misaligned-mismatched-size-in-flags-list)

On the review history page, the items look rather squished:

[image]

Furthermore, the font size is different between links and non-links (in the case of deleted posts).

Is it possible to increase the padding between items or make the font size of the title links smaller? The line-spacing looks OK.

A further step would be to allow options such as "Touch", "Comfortable", "Cozy", "Compact" like Gmail and Google Calendar:

[image: Gmail appearance options]

Comment: I cannot replicate this on Chrome or FireFox. What browser version are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in all Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m, Firefox 37.0a2, and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17498 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yup, confirmed with Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) on Arch Linux.

Comment: Confirmed with Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m - Windows 7 x64

Comment: I'm so glad I'm not the only one reacting to this, I was worried this was an intended design change. It looks like my grandfathers iPhone set to super-zoom-levels. Absolutely horrible. http://i.stack.imgur.com/WmcoU.png

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 35.0.1, Windows 8.1.  Was this fixed?