# Vote count and titles misaligned in flag summary

Tags: bug, design

I've been seeing the following misalignment since I joined SO but didn't report it. Apparently it's been [reported before and fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283878/10794031), however the fix isn't working for me.

It's only noticeable if the question doesn't have a green box around the vote count indicating an accepted answer.

OS: Win10 Pro

Browser: Firefox 75.0

[image]

**EDIT:**

I just noticed there are other places where the misalignment happens:

[image]

Comment: Very well could be related to [Dark Mode Beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits?cb=1). They're still trying to get all the bugs out of it.

Comment: @Chipster hahaha I [reported it there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396694/10794031) and CodyGray sent me here...I've also been seeing this for a full year before dark-mode. Dunno, I'm not a web designer. It does raise the question: How many more folks have been seeing this?

Comment: I don't think it's misaligned. What you don't see it the box that indicates if it has an accepted answer, because none of those in your image has. For reference:  [Not Misaligned - Ligth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUxEb.png) & [Not Misasligned - Dak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fTWy.png)

Comment: @Scratte I would accept your comment if you converted it to an answer. I tried reading the other threads on this issue but still couldn't understand the logic of the (mis)aligned alignment.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an answer. It's an explanation though. (Pardon my spelling in it). I still think the box should be visible even if there are no accepted answers, like on one's profile. Perhaps your "bug" will get the attention to make it happen :) You're welcome to add in my images if you want to modify your Question.

Comment: @Scratte it's an "option". I haven't worked on "presentation layers" for some years now. But I recall having done this both ways: in a given row 1) centering the icon on the text 2) aligning any text within icon with remaining text 3) align lower border of icon with text line.