# Spam and offensive flag red button thingys overfloweth

Tags: bug, design

The spam and offensive flag red button thingys in the user flag summary are right-padded, which means they runneth over into the word "helpful"

[image]

Comment: Yup @Mat, cheers. I've re-titled t'other question to make it more generic.