# Please revert back to previous design until all the obvious bugs in the current design has been fixed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

**Please revert back to the previous design until [all obvious bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update) in the current design has been fixed.**

Some examples:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278000/1400768
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277208/1400768 (bug 3)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277209/1400768

(I'm not against change per se, but releasing bugged software when the bugs are known is a blasphemy. I understand about releasing software often, but the obvious, in-the-face bugs should be fixed - smaller bugs can be weed out by the community)

Since the bugs are listed in that question, I don't see any visible update on the bug fixes.

What is the point of asking us for feedback when you guys release the new design without even fixing the design bugs in the feedback thread? (I understand that this is community testing, but with none of the bugs addressed after testing on Meta.SO, the decision to release really baffles me).

Some of them are opinionated, **but many of them are actual design bugs**, which sooner or later are sure to receive **duplicated bug report**, and it is a waste of time of the community to handle all those duplicates.

**This is not an expression of opinion on how the current design looks like. I just disagree with the way the design is released without weeding out the obvious bugs already listed in the feedback thread**.

Comment: Old design was way better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We won't be maintaining 2 themes - we will however address all the bugs as quick as we can. A few hundred fixes went out over the past 24 hours and we'll be squashing some more here in a bit.

Answer (score 7):

We're supposed to report the bugs as we find them - many bugs have been ironed out of the design while it was being tested here on meta, but some bugs will only appear when the mainstream audience uses it with mainstream content.

I vote we keep it and report bugs here.

As for *existing* bugs, they'll be fixed in time. I looked through the list, and I don't see any that impede operation of the site.

Comment: `What is the point of asking us for feedback when you guys release the new design without even fixing the design bugs in the feedback thread?` The bugs are there, **for months**, why not **fix them** first?

Comment: @nhahtdh SE designers are busy people. Trust me, bugs will be fixed in their time. The perfect is the enemy of the good, if we wait to release a design until it's perfect we won't ever release a design.

Comment: There are 6-8 weeks for them to fix, and the obvious bugs in the list should be weeded out first. It's good to release often, but at least those obvious bugs should have been cleaned up, even more so when they are already reported.

Comment: @nhahtdh Sometimes it's simply hard to keep up with what hasn't been fixed, it's an imperfect world. We're certainly not leaving things buggy for 6-8 weeks though, all the bugs listed in this question are already fixed for the next build.

Comment: @NickCraver: Would you please post it as an answer? And I think it is possible to convert the feedback into your internal bug reports, where you can keep track of the progress.

Comment: @Undo but old design was almost perfect... just needed few tweaks.

Comment: @nhahtdh meta is the source of truth here to what has/haven't been fixed - we track across questions very well but many answers to a single question we need to improve tooling on. We have no separate tracking system - we're *very* light on overhead so things move much faster.