# Is this new flat theme mandatory or is there an option to change it back?

Tags: discussion, design

I noticed today that Stack Overflow has changed to a more flat UI. I have nothing against flat UIs, but I am used to the old theme and it is more visually appealing to me.

Is there an option to switch between the old design and the new one?

Comment: Yes it's new and no, you can't change it.

Comment: Major difference I feel is that unread/non-viewed questions are no more **bold**.

Comment: If you want, you can grab a copy of the [old CSS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19563971#19563971) and a browser addon (e.g. Stylish) to apply the old theme - at least until they change the site structure enough to break it.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I will have to make a grasemoney script to change it back.

Comment: I like flat design and it would take time to adapt to the change but `font-weight: bold;` for the anchor tag of unread questions is what I would wish for. :)

Comment: new theme is tough to comprehend and pain to eyes too :(

Comment: What the heck happened, things just got ten times harder to read? Hopefully my burning eyes will adapt in time. I actually like the new buttons and some of the design (profile pages look good), but the question titles on the overview pages got really small!

Comment: I dislike this new strange Stack Overflow.

Comment: ahhh ,this new look is a nightmare. My eyes are aking. The designer should be fired and should be charged because of bodily injury.

Comment: Don't like the new design.

Comment: I see unread  questions listed are already lighter enough.. they still become more lighter on hover..

Comment: Dear SE designers and developers,  I'm a 4 years old member on Stack Overflow and try to be an active user on `c#` tag. Sincerely, this new flat/light theme effected me **SO BAD**. I can't follow the questions carefully, I can't follow which question I looked because of light highlighting, I can't concentrated on the code blocks where the real problem belongs. This hurts so much. Even if you _really_ decide this will be the final theme for general design on Stack Overflow, for the love of god, or what ever you believe, please, put an option to use old theme at least. Thank you.

Comment: Ahhh change for the sake of change. What a waste of time. Why do major websites keep doing this once in a while? _Why?_ "Don't worry, you'll get used to it" Yes I know but so what?

Comment: Question and comment should be separated by a line.

Comment: The question "highlight" color is much more difficult for my bad eyes to see... other than that I haven't seen many issues with the new stylesheet

Comment: Questions "grayed out" based on ignored tags are unreadable.  **way** too light,

Comment: Awful.  More whitespace (always with the whitespace) and a lighter-weight font.

Comment: Man, why are there so many questions about this now instead of a month ago when the devs were asking for feedback? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update (Yeah, I know. Lots of people don't visit meta.)

Comment: The new colors in this new scheme are very hard to distinguish - highlighted and non-highlighted questions are near impossible to tell apart when not looking at the screen at a right angle.

Comment: The new font is harder to read.

Comment: I for one welcome our new flat wide spaced overlords.

Comment: My question is where was all this feedback when they announced it 3 months ago?

Comment: I didn't like it when it came out on meta, posted on the feedback question, and here again. There is no attention to contrast, spacing, or convention. Ugh. Once again going to have to manually do work to create a user script to fix poor design.

Comment: I like the new look.

Comment: The new 'style' is horrible. [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/) pulled a similar stunt a few weeks ago, I no longer visit.

Comment: Honestly can't even tell the difference.

Comment: @Jehan: You must be a 'web designer'. ;)

Comment: [My eyes, my eyes](http://www.waterwisepoolsandspas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/My_eyes.png)

Comment: Might as well make the site in Comic Sans. Everyone can read it, and we all hate it equally.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Some of us brought up a number of readability issues when they created the Meta Stack Exchange styling, as a preview to where SO would eventually head.  Those concerns were either deleted or ignored.  (There are still a large number of visual problems with the MSE design, nine months later.)

Comment: What the hell???  I am an old fart, and can't see this!

Comment: Change sucks. [Think of the children!](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: Hey guys! Can someone help me? I must have been bitten by a radioactive spider, because I gained super-sight and am actually able to distinguish with no effort whatsoever the colour of highlighted vs non highlighted questions! The new UI is fresher, and nicer and, seriously, if you are not able to answer anymore just because the colours have changed the problem does not lie in the colours...

Comment: Everything just... blends together too much. Nothing is differentiated.

Comment: I don't know why this design would be described as "flat". Stack Overflow never had a non-"flat" UI!

Comment: **Designers:**  Consider for a minute that utility, especially on a site like this, trumps other design priorities.  The best can make this happen and still end up with something that looks good at the end of the day.  This new site design is a real killer to usability.  Who cares if the old site was ugly.  I liked the ugly.  Why?  Because I could read it much more easily than this, the higher contrast was made it much easier to spot things, etc.

Answer (score 78):

The editor on StackOverflow has lost its mono-spaced font (not so here).

This makes it much more difficult to type in nicely formatted source code snippets. It's a major pain in the a... now!

Also, I was in the middle of editing a longer answer regarding ImageMagick's `compare` command, using images to [visually support my explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27976171/359307). I was almost finished, when suddenly somehow all pairs of images which were fitting nicely before (side by side) started to layout in a vertical stack (because the column width changed). I had to re-process, resize and re-upload all my carefully prepared images.

When that was done, another change happened, making the column even smaller again. I had to resort to changing my image embedding code again. I lost 1 hour, and I also lost a lot of motivation to spend any special effort in the future to work on good answers. Only fast shoots will it be from now on, unless this is just a temporary change!

Comment: The worst part of this is that it was also a proportional-width font here for a while before they changed it back to monospace (probably in response to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/277296#277296)). Did they forget to push it to the SO branch or something? One of the most blatant regressions I've seen.

Comment: OK, so as it turns out, it seems to be affecting the editor only when *editing* a post, but not when composing a new question or answer, and this is consistent on both sites. The monospace font has also been lost in the comment form but that doesn't matter as much because comments can't contain multiline code blocks anyway.

Comment: This is a serious problem.  There's also another question — [Can we have Courier back in editor?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/can-we-have-courier-back-in-editor) — addressing this.  It is a major retrograde step; a bug; a regression.

Comment: I agree that the monospace issue is annoying, but honestly, you shouldn't rely on the width of the page for your own content. No website uses the same design for the entire lifespan of the site. Things *will* change, and content *will* shift around. That's the nature of the Internet. FWIW your images still fall onto new lines in the mobile design, and probably on the apps too. -- As an aside, you *can* manually specify the width of an image here by using HTML to insert it into your post. You don't have to resize them all to make them fit.

Comment: "a major pain in the [ayyy](http://markp427.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/fonz.jpg) now!"

Comment: This problem seems to have been fixed, I'm relieved to say.

Comment: @animuson: Thanks for your feedback. As a matter of fact, I changed my Markdown code for image insertion to `<img src="..." width="...">` in order to make it fit (when I was forced to make the second set of changes while editing it). You are right about *"no websit uses same design for entire lifespan"*. But I also can expect some degree of stability for a website that hosts user-submitted content. Unforch, the image insertion code does not support `width="X%"`, it only supports `width="NNN"`...

Answer (score 61):

1. I think the new blue review buttons don't fit to the design very well and are very distracting. I find the old black ones much better:

[image]

Perheps if they had at least the same color as the other text around which is a little bit darker:

[image]

2. Also the comment for the suggested edit in the review is no longer highlighted so it's more difficult to spot it now:

[image]

Comment: You might want to post this in a separate question with `bug` tag.

Comment: I think the new buttons are there to put of robo-reviewers...

Comment: It bothers me the that the buttons are 3d, yet the design of everything else is flat.

Comment: +1.  I spent an embarrassing number of minutes thinking that I accidentally highlighted the buttons and somehow couldn't undo it.

Answer (score 28):

Currently there is no official option to switch back to the old design. You *could* take the old CSS (you can probably find it on the Wayback Machine), and an extension like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) and manually apply it.

I see this as being much like the heartache everyone had back when the [new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210012/would-it-be-possible-to-lighten-the-color-of-the-new-top-bar) - pretty soon everyone got used to it and there's no more heartache.

I'll be honest, right now I prefer the old design to the current one. I plan to give it a few days before taking any action to revert, though - it worked with the top bar.

Comment: Honestly the top bar wasn't really good or bad IMO. It was a useful feature. The flat ui seems to have removed a lot of the useful color differentiators and text semantics.

Comment: Can't knock visual appeal as a reason, though.  I mean, you do have to look at it to use it!

Comment: [Wayback machine CSS file link](http://web.archive.org/web/20150101021716cs_/http:/cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=6916350d45f0)...

Comment: _doesn't even remember what the top bar looked like_

Answer (score 6):

#### Why not just fix some things ?

Flat themes are very popular at the moment and this began just before Windows 8 came out some years earlier. Almost everywhere I'm looking at now (not only on *this* screen but also out there..) looks like I'm seeing a Metro desktop and flat applications everywhere.

I'll be honest : I don't like Win8/Metro, was used since WinXP to the very appealing colors and effects, things you only saw long ago in video games, movies and Apple things...

Flat designs has those flaws : you're unsure of the boundary of frames because the human eyes are naturally programmed to focus based on **contrast and colors** (hence the importance of shadows)

But yes, it's a matter of **fashion/trend**, while the "flat" style is just a Windows 3.1 style with thinner lines (smaller pixels) and aliased edges, because it's possible.

So yes, **it's ugly**, but we have countless example of "fashionable" ugly things... Truth is : "you can't contest when it's popular". Whether one or even thousands don't like it doesn't matter.

That's why it's difficult to admit the SO flat style lacks **contrast and colors** for the most of us because the feedback about came **too late** after the thing was widely adopted.

That means I, for example, will deal with it, **but that doesn't mean**

- I like the new styling
- I agree with the change
- I'm satisfied

**I don't !** Just like I don't feel happy when I'm looking at something reminding me Windows 8 and those big ugly monochrome squares everywhere.

So in the end, all I'm expecting is :

- a dimmer SO interface, less bright because the **white** surely burns my eyes from time to time.
- perhaps the returns of some colouring for my mostly "visually receptive brain" (the black and white icon above this editbox make me believe we are 25 years back then when I played with Commodore)

Hopefully, next progress would be the return of some very old styles like Windows 98 SE title bar; you know ? that shaded blue background (which was a great improvement at the time) because after **black and white** and noborder frames, what else could the human (re)invent ..?

This is not a rant towards Microsoft or SE designers. You're all doing interresting things. It's just a matter of disagreeing on what is appealing and **helpfull in the ease of use** of the (new) platform visual, **which are both subjective opinions.**

Where was I when the feedback began on the new styling ?
I was there, I saw the Meta info from StackOverflow, I've read the post and related topics and many comments. Many users seemed soooo enjoying the new thing I though twice then decided not to be the ugly mood breaker, and believe several long lived and notorious users here will point out most of ballant design. And they did a **GREAT** job. Most of the things I disliked where whiped out. But the above remains :

- too few colors.
- not enough contrast to separate frames (where are my Favourite Tags topics ?)
- too much white.
- (I have 10/10 both eyes even if I spend 7 up to 10 hours a day in front of a computer in the last 10 years, so I don't mind the small font, but I don't know of others)

Thanks for reading. I won't be upset if nothing changes. If the current trend is for widespace, monochrome things and *clear* (or wasted) spacing... so go for it.

**Neither the old or new design will please everyone anyway.** (and I didn't say I liked 100% the old one - I didn't say either to get an interface as "fantastic" as Science Fiction and Fantasy or Role Play Gaming sellow SE sites)

Answer (score -4):

This is a new theme that SO are working on, so not likely to be any way back. Welcome to the future. :)

More info: [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update)

Comment: It's not about getting the old style back because like any other improvement for the worse there is no going back. There are however few things where the readability needs optimizations.