# Can we have Courier back in editor?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When editing a post, it is irritating not to have in the editor a font whose letters all have the same space. In particular, it is hard to edit code blocks.

Please change that back.

Comment: Since this [only affects the editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283630/is-this-flat-theme-new-or-is-there-an-option-to-change-it-back/283635#comment143121_283635), as I have found, this is more of a bug than a feature request. I'm hoping it's just an oversight while tweaking the design for programming sites like SO.

Comment: The absence of constant-width font in the editor makes ASCII art and table layout impossible.  It is a very serious retrograde step — regression.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've pushed a fix to this. It will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Thank you; it makes all the difference in the world!