# Updated "award your bounty" button style

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounty

Following the [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update of 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update) thread.

After the design update, I've noticed that the "award the bounty" button look is confusing:

[image]

It looks as it is already awarded but it is still active. Mouse overing the button makes it not bold and the button box/container becomes smaller:

[image]

Before the redesign, it looked [this way](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/bounty-award-indicators.png) - a bit not legible (disabled) becoming active/enabled/legible on mouse over.

<sup>I've looked through the recent posts and I think nobody complained about this particular design issue.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not intentional. I have pushed a fix, should be on live after our next production build.

Comment: Looks good now, thank you for the quick fix!