# How to find my own answer quickly?

Tags: discussion, support, search

Lets take an example of this question, [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update), on which I've answered (two). Right now there are approx. 70 (seventy) answers and I am looking for my answers, **How can I find it quickly?**

Site has following tabs right now,

[image]

But even this way, it's hard to find my own answers.

If site has one more tab, named "my answers",

[image]

By selecting, "my answers" tab I'll list with the answer which I've given. No other users answers will be list here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is rare for a post to receive so many answers that you could have problems finding a specific one on the page. And for the **vast** majority of questions you'd only ever post just one answer. So for there to be any question with so many answers that a separate tab is needed just to list your own, is... vanishingly small. It is not worth the effort of the dev team to implement such a tab.

For such an exceptional post, you can use *search* to find your own answers. Type in `inquestion:this user:me` into the search box on the top right of the question page and the search engine will list *only your answers for that question*.

If I replace `user:me` with your user id, the search engine fills in the post id and you get [your one answer listed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A277200+user%3A1603234).