# Give the old theme for the main site back

Tags: feature-request

This isn't really a question, it's a request. I request that you give us the old (a.k.a. actually usable, unlike the new one) theme back, at the very least in a form of an opt-in.

(No, seriously, the new theme is just bad. Stop this madness.)

Comment: Is there a list of everything that has been changed? It seems most of it are small adjustments / changes and I would be interested in seeing a full list.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give a list of concrete problems.

Comment: @FredOverflow that question is a question, this is a request.

Comment: The main problem from my point of view is that question summaries are hard to read using this font and weight, and its practically impossible to differentiate between 'read' links and 'unread' links. Oddly this is almost exactly the same complaint as 'The Register' redesign, I guess this is seen as 'cool' by web designers.

Comment: Other problems include: 1) the site not being distinct enough from the meta (no, seriously, it's not); 2) I can't immediately tell visited and not visited links apart; 3) the vote arrows are just bad; 4) spaaaaaces; 5) countless more.

Comment: @Griwes Ah, *now* we’re getting somewhere. I disagree with your 3&4, but the other points are good, and merit separate, serious bug reports/feature requests.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think there need to be separate reports - the only sane way to fix this is to provide a "let me select the look for me" option.

Comment: @Griwes Nonsense, and you know of course that you won’t get that anyway.

Comment: This is just a dataless rant. Either list problems you have -- contribute to the meta post on the issue -- or keep quiet.

Comment: The site isn't usable anymore?

Comment: We have started on reverting some changes in a user style script. This is far from an optimal solution, but it kinda for me http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283852/508666

Answer (score -2):

There was a request for [feedback all the way back in November](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update). You had the opportunity to voice your concerns.

If you're really unhappy with it, [use or make a userstyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow) and stick that on instead.

Comment: When I go through the “voiced concerns” in that thread, half of those high voted issues are still present, so obviously the style isn’t ready for the big public facing SO yet.

Comment: Nonsense. SE doesn't ever listen to serious feedback, so it would have been even more useless than this request.

Comment: "SE Doesn't ever listen to serious feedback" - so what do you expect to happen as a result of this question exactly?

Answer (score -4):

The web designers get paid for working at Stack Exchange 40 hours per week. I mean, they gotta do *something*!