# Suggestion to reinstate the divider between the post and the first comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Since the new design update I found myself reading the first comment as being part of the question a few times. A divider would be a better indication that you're at the comment section.

### Current situation

[image]

---

### Proposed situation

[image]

It's also more consistent with the look and feel of the other comments, the current situation makes the first comment stand out.

Comment: Meh. It's pretty clear to me, what with the tags and the user card being in between.

Comment: It's not so clear when you're tired or the post contains other images.

Comment: Don't SO while tired perhaps? Really, its just a question of getting used to the design. The user card and tags are much clearer visual indicators where a question ends and the comments start than a thin grey line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added a divider line per your suggestion. It will be on live after the next production build.