# Darker color for favorite tags

Tags: discussion, design, tag-watching

On the Stack Overflow site, right now, the css used for favorite tags is this:

```
.tagged-interesting {
    rgba(255,245,222,0.7)
}
```

I recommend a darker color or removing the opacity:

```
.tagged-interesting {
    rgba(255,245,222,1)
}
```

It just seems too light and its hard for me to clearly see which tags are favorite tags.

Comment: This seemed to change overnight last night. The Beta  sister-sites (that I frequent) still have the former colouring.

Comment: I would suggest to consider highlighting favourite tag, instead of or in addition to the whole question (for example `border: 2px solid #08f` or stronger background/font).