# Enhancing the readability of user page and questions pages

Tags: discussion, design

It's been about *2 weeks in Internet time (2-4 days normal time)* since the new design went into effect on Stack Overflow, and I'm still finding some things difficult to read.

Issue #1 of mine is the background color of the questions that include my favorite tags. I've already left an answer on that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/283819#283819), and there's other similar questions about the issue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283871/darker-color-for-favorite-tags) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283937/contrast-on-highlighted-favorites-is-too-low). So this question is not about that issue #1 of mine.

Issue #2 is the readability of the user page. It's so blue everywhere. I suggest changing it to be like how Meta Stack Overflow is. Notice how the links to each of your answers/questions ***are not pink but a blackish color***.

[image]

But on Stack Overflow the links are a blueish color:

[image]

I find this to be way too much blue and personally annoying to look at. So I suggest changing it to the same blackish color that's on Meta Stack Overflow or similar, so it would look something like this:

[image]

Also, I wouldn't mind the [regular questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) pages being the same blackish link color. Find it very much easier to read without the bright blueish color jumping out at me so hard.

Comment: Your name is "bluet" and you don't like blue? :)

Comment: I don't really see any _evidence_ that supports your request. What if we do this change and then someone doesn't like the blackish tone? What is fundamentally better having black than blue? Seems to me it is more a matter of taste or do you really have difficulty to read blue (this is what you said first, but then don't expand on it)? Personally, I think it is quite an internet-standard to make links blue, so I think it makes sense here.

Comment: I would complain for example that already visited links have no hover effect anymore, which I find a lack of usability

Comment: Blue is fine.  This particular blue is a bit on the weak side.