# New Syntax Highlight Colors for Dark Theme are Wildly Different with Change of Highlight Engine

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting, dark-mode

All, after following the post of trials of the new highlight scheme (I can't recall if it is from highlight.js to google or vice-versa) the new engine is apparently in use on StackOverflow now. The colors are wildly different from before. The reds are now burnt orange and the rest of the syntax colors for C are not even close to the other engine, e.g.

[image]

I was able to find an older image here:

[image]

Is there any way this can be made consistent with what we had a few days ago?

Comment: it's google to highlight.js. Though why we made the change, I don't know. Prettify was perfectly fine.

Comment: More than consistence with the old days, I'd rather ask that these colors are made consistent everywhere, in today's product. StackSnippets editors are still using (yet) an other color scheme.

Comment: Let me just add my two cents here and say that it's unbelievable to me how anybody would like having the same color for function names (`puts`), variables/macros (`stdout`, `NULL`) and integer constants (`-1`). Let alone the same color for [types, keywords and preprocessor directives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuXF4.png). This is bonkers. I would suggest you to incorporate this in your post, since the real problem here is not that the theme changed, but that the new theme is hideous.

Comment: Comparing two different code snippets is not super useful; could you find where the bottom code snippet is and then show how it looks now instead of how a completely different snippet of code looks now?

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353994/397555) on MSO covers similar ground.

Comment: Java highlighting sucks for sure. Aside from black, it seems like there are only two colors being used. ughh.

Comment: @10Rep Maybe for the languages you follow, but not for everyone. There were many bugs reported over the years with Prettify.

Comment: As it says in [the announcement post for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401031/how-does-the-highlight-js-change-affect-stack-overflow-specifically?cb=1) bugs, etc., should be discussed on [the original MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/194720).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm still not a fan. Almost any highlighting system will have bugs. And I've noticed that highlight.js takes slightly longer. And I agree with Marco Bonelli, mainly because orange is used for keywords in python, c#, and many more languages. And plus, google is a much bigger company than whoever made highlight.js.

Comment: The size of the company behind a library sounds pretty irrelevant if one of those libraries is no longer maintained by said company.

Comment: is the syntax highlighting working in meta? If yes, then also include the code blocks under each picture for a real comparison. Nothing like comparing 2 completely different code blocks.

Comment: @10Rep “Prettify was perfectly fine.” — LOL. I mean, no. It objectively wasn’t. It had been unmaintained for years, contained numerous bugs, and the individual language support was *severely* lacking compared to virtually every other modern syntax highlighter (as in, it only supported subsets of language tokens, and was based on versions of these languages of about a decade ago). Stack Overflow syntax highlighting was comically bad, to the point of being a running gag. The new highlighter is vastly better in general. Stack Overflow just needs to tweak their (currently too basic) CSS.

Comment: (That being said, yes, the Java lexer is bizarre, and actually breaks several Highlight.js rules. Somebody should definitely take a stab at improving it.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Okay, maybe Prettify wasn't perfect. Nor is this, either. I really wish functions were blue. It's messing with my brain. I think SO needs to work on the CSS.

Comment: The orange was too flashy. It has been changed. That's better now.

Comment: This doesn't just effect C/C++, but all shell utilities like `sed` and `awk` as well as plain on shell scripts. I've been looking critically at how the new syntax is applies to these tools as well, and for some, like `awk`, then new syntax highlight makes it unreadable. This is exacerbated by the dark theme where the dark-gray question background has little contrast with the burnt-orange or baby-puke green. In C/C++ where you have alternating declarations and `scanf()` in between you end up with orange-green-orange-green-orange.... that literally all melts together.

Comment: [Related on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354541/332043)

Comment: This is all just a clown car blur that has no meaning. It's only justification is that someone once read you're supposed to have color highlighting and for no other reason.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Please can you do as TylerH requests regarding making the comparison identical.

Answer (score 8):

This is a comment that is too big to fit into a comment — especially as it needs an image.

I find it weird that in C code, the `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` functions are highlighted as 'standard functions' but the `fgets()` function is not (see [How do I print the binary of characters from an input file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083535/15168) for the original answer):

[image: mixed colours for standard C functions]

For consistency, those functions should all be the same colour.  When a function name gets promoted to 'standard' and gets the colour is subjective, but for C code, it would be reasonable to cover the functions in the latest C standard (with maybe `gets()` also included because it *was* a standard function but isn't any more — unless it gets coloured a virulent red to indicate it should never be used, pun intended).

Or maybe the criterion isn't 'standard function', but I'm not sure what the alternative criterion is.

Another example is at [How to read integers from a file without knowing how many integers per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64086134/15168) — it doesn't highlight `fgets()` again, nor `strtol()`.  And, if it survives so that it is visible to users without 10K reputation, the code in [Storing two arrays in shared memory using shmat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64085719/15168) has lots of user-defined functions that are not highlighted, but it also has POSIX C functions that could be regarded as standard but they are not highlighted.

In my opinion, consistency within an image (code segment) is important.  I'm not so worried about comparisons with what was present with Prettify compared to highlight.js.  (Oh, and if it isn't clear, I'm using dark mode display.  I've not checked what happens with light mode display.)

Comment: The only real solution seems to be to disable function highlighting completely. Library functions are not core language, and if some functions are to be highlighted, then _all_ the functions should be. This is not possible unless the highlighter includes a parser of the language syntax, which isn't feasible at all.

Comment: I guess adding a few keywords to the C language is welcome as a pull request to the highlight.js project. What's more concerning is that their current color (orange) is the same as the color for declaration names and number literals, and that it's so wildly different from non-standard function names. A dark blue tone would be much nicer.

Comment: @Ruslan but... C standard library functions *are* core language.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if you look into the C Standard, you'll find two large sections there: "6. Language" and "7. Library". So these are quite separated.

Comment: @Ruslan the standard is named "The C Programming Language".

Comment: @Jonathan [how about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354753/190417)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yeah, and this standard allows for a conforming implementation (so called _freestanding implementation_) to not implement most of the Library (see 4/6).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — differential colouring on `sizeof` is weird.  There is lots of room for improvement here (and there).

Comment: @Ruslan — the number of questions on SO about free-standing implementations of C is vanishingly small.  You are strictly correct but that is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: My point is that the C standard functions are not much more important than e.g. POSIX ones, so highlighting the former so prominently while ignoring the latter will only lead to confusion, rather than help reading. But of course it's just my opinion, rather than absolute truth, so I won't argue further.

Comment: The reason is this: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/c.js#L11 ***"Until C is actually different than C++ there is no reason to auto-detect C as it's own language since it would just fail auto-detect testing or simply match with C++."***

Comment: @Ruslan  — Standard C is a lot more significant than POSIX. Otherwise, you open the door for ”Windows is more important than POSIX”, etc.  In most respects, the details are immaterial and consistency and explainability are what matter most.  Personally, I'd be happy with non-keyword identifiers uniformly in one colour, keywords in another, strings and numbers in one or two more colors, character constants in another, and punctuation (just about anything else) in another.  .

Comment: There are a few tricky issues to deal with — syntax highlighting for macro definitions, treating `true`, `false`, `bool` as keywords even though they aren't, ditto for names such as `alignof` which are mapped to keywords with an underscore prefix (`<stdalign.h>`, `<stdnoreturn.h>`), semi-normal preprocessor extensions such as `#warning` — but more or less any sane, consistent rule would be sufficient.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — hmmm: good find.  That's infuriating!  The last time I looked, C++ had a whole bundle of keywords that aren't in C, so that at least the lists of keywords for the two languages should be different.  If you write `int class = 1;` in C, that's valid (even if not advisable; I wouldn't write that) and `class` is just an identifier — unlike C++ where it is a keyword and the syntax is invalid.  Grump!  I guess we may have to fix the project to get SO to support C syntax sanely.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — see also https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/c-like.js where it says: _In the future the intention is to split out the C/C++ grammars distinctly since they are separate languages.  They will likely share a common foundation though, and this file sets the groundwork for that…_  I think it says something about where the minds of the people i/c highlight.js are concentrated (I get the impression they don't care much about C).  Lines 109-117 explain a lot about why some functions do get highlighted and many others do not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so apparently SO the corporation thought that since prettify is not being supported, they would switch to a library that is supported and that they would get the new languages for free, and we the contributors (read: the product) would then happily contribute those rules for them.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala To be fair it’s reasonable: It was previously completely impossible to get any lexer improvements into Stack Overflow (and prettify was *bad*). Now it’s possible. That’s a huge step in the right direction. Furthermore, the project is actually extremely responsive to PRs. On the flip side, writing a good language definition for C++ (and, by implication, for C, since these are currently identical) is really *hard* and requires a lot of effort. I’m willing to actively contribute (and I’m already working on this) but the C++ lexer is a larger than one person job.

Comment: @KonradRudolph — The C++ syntax for numbers with single quote separators embedded (e.g. `0b1101’0010’1101’0110`) is rather hard to parse for sure. That's not valid in standard C, though — neither the base (binary) nor the punctuation (but some C compilers recognize the base).  Raw string literals are another nightmare notation in C++ that are not present in C.  So the lexer for C++ may be different from the lexer for C in the long run.  That said, some naïve users will write C++ code in a question tagged C, which also will give the system conniptions.  'Tis tricky.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler None of the things you’ve mentioned are particularly hard to parse. What’s hard (actually, impossible) is *template declarations*.  While lexical analysis doesn’t care about templates, the highlight.js language definition attempts to parse class and function headers to highlight the definition name, so it does require at least an approximate understanding of templates. Anyway, I agree that the “right” solution is to split these two definitions up.

Comment: @KonradRudolph — If you use a formal lexical analyzer, no, but they're messy if you work with ad hoc pseudo-lexers.  I've not.lookedvto see what highlight.js currently does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Highlight.js already supports number separators and raw strings. I haven’t checked if the support is actually always correct but at a glance it seems spec conforming.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, JonathanLeffler: FYI, here’s my WIP PR: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2728

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The discrepancy in highlighting on some built-ins vs others is on the way to being fixed: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2973

Comment: Thanks, @JoshGoebel.  I get notices from GitHub too.  I'm hoping to be able to help eventually, but I'm not primarily a JavaScript programmer, and life is just a tad convoluted at the moment (and not primarily because of COVID-19).  But it is good news that the separation of C and C++ has started.