# Change highlighting for read topics

Tags: feature-request, design

The new styles for stackoverflow sites seems quite clean, but there's something I consider is missing in these changes.

The ability to see what topics have I visited and which ones I haven't. 
The highlighting was clearly different in the previous version of the site and it was easy to filter and check just the non visited topics.

I found this quite interesting when using the search, filtering by tags or even to know if I visited that same question months ago.

Now this is impossible and my workflow in the site has worsen a lot.

This needs to be changed...
[image]

Comment: I did not expect a 10k user to post a meta question with all the required tags mindlessly filled in.

Comment: @BoltClock I consider it something to be "discussed" for the "support" team and the rest of users, I'm asking for a "feature-request" to change an existing feature, which could even be consider a "bug" by some, and which definitely is a matter of color conventions within the "design". Tags make sense to me.

Comment: "quite clean" ... questions with favorite tags are a bit *too* clean for my taste. The RGB(255,248,232) is hardly distinguishable from white for me. It could have gone unnoticed because I don't have favorite tags on Meta.

Comment: I actually find the questions feed to be harder to read, not to mention the grayed out questions which are even more harder to read. Seems like I'd have to boost up the contrast in my color correction settings. Plus, I have noticed that on my laptop that I now have an horizontal scrollbar and the layout no longer fits in screen, why is that and why hasn't it been designed with "responsive" in mind?

Comment: Right now the two colors are `#0c65a5` and `#0077cc` which has a [colour difference of just 69](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html#fg=0C65A5,bg=0077CC), which is pretty low compared to the [meta color difference of 217](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html#fg=666666,bg=http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html#fg=666666,bg=BE1E2D). Something like `#00416f` might work better as the color for the visited link [(preview)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hXdQA.png).

Comment: Also contrast of pale blue on pale yellow background is very hard to read. Old theme had better contrast

Comment: Came here after trying the new scheme for a couple of days, but I'm still not accustomed (to the lack of visible information about what links I visited on search and profile pages) and don't think I'll ever going to see the difference (on my calibrated screen). (I even halted my otherwise regular clean-up contributions due to this). So I decided to make a meta-post about it after searching if it wasn't already asked. So here's my upvote. @KevinBrown: yep, that would work for me. I *think* it is font-smoothing that makes the small color difference even less visible on text.

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to post the exact same feature request: to highlight questions that have already been viewed. In my questions list it seems there is no indication if I've already opened/viewed a certain question.

This question got me thinking about modifying the styling for pages manually through developer console, but you wouldn't want to do that every time you load a page. So I found an extension called **Stylebot** (there are probably others similar). You can very quickly add a stylesheet to a website, this is what I added for *stackoverflow.com*, works well for me, and didn't have to wait:

```
#qlist-wrapper a:visited {
    color: #bbb ;
}
```