# New page layout too wide for 1024px

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

The facelifted page is 1030px wide (1000 px plus 2x 15px horizontal padding).

[image: new page layout]

The old page was 980px wide (no padding).

[image: old page layout]

This means: For a negligible net width increase of 20px it needlessly forces a horizontal scrollbar on 1024px wide screens.

I think that's a step back. Mainly because SO is not a site that generally puts emphasis on wide-screen layout and because it doesn't seem to make use of the added 20px anyway. In other words: People with 1920px wide screens won't even notice the width increase.

I know that 1024px horizontal display resolution is on its way out, but this layout change doesn't really seem to make a big difference how the page appears.

So I assume it was simply an oversight.

Accommodating users who still have an older laptop with a small screen in active use - like me :) - would not be too much to ask?

Comment: With a vertical scrollbar showing in Chrome, just the display window needs to be 1051px wide to avoid the horizontal scrollbar. ...but we're all using HD widescreens, so we're all good. :)

Comment: Something around 940px wide would be nice for those who use two windows side-by-side on 1920px wide monitors.

Comment: IMO, the new design is generally rather unnecessarily spacious.

Comment: I like a cramped style better.  It goes better with my cubicle.

Comment: The padding was [specifically requested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277223/621962) in the feedback post so that content wasn't right up against the side of the screen. The overall width should be adjusted inward to accommodate the new padding, though.

Comment: Let me add that not everyone uses a full-screen browser. I have a 1980px screen but my browser width is set to ~1080px. I don't have a scrollbar but I'd actually prefer my browser even narrower - some other site forces me to this minimum width.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1920xx wide monitor - 1980 was a typo.

Comment: @cpburnz Or for those of us with 1280 and a docked chat/other window - my browser maxes out at somewhere around 950-960px wide, if I remember right...

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the page appearing to be slightly too large on my netbook as well. We don't all have modern sized screens.

Comment: I also see the horizontal scroll bar. I am tempted to manually squash it with the same ferocity that one would use when quickly disposing of a gnat or mosquito.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 and I usually browse the web with another app snapped to the right. My screen resolution is 1366×768. So, my screen is 1024 browser + 22 separator + 320 other app.

Comment: In 2015, I think that most (non-mobile) users have more than 1024px of resolution width available. IMHO, I understand the argument presented, but I think its one of those things where users of extremely old browsers / machines don't necessarily need to be accommodated. Kinda like making your website IE6 compliant

Comment: @chiliNUT Sorry, but... **A)** Your assumption is wrong. Read the other comments, where people say they don't always have their browsers at full screen. Or are using netbooks. Just because *you* are using a bigger screen, don't jump to conclusion that everybody does. Also, **B)** your comparison is flawed. This is *nothing* like making your page IE6 compatible. Not even close. My entire point is that making a page 1030px wide serves no purpose when it could be 1000px wide with no ill-effects .

Comment: @chiliNUT Let me quote: *"I think its one of those things where users of extremely old browsers / machines don't necessarily need to be accommodated."* That's an assumption and a single-handed conclusion in one sentence right there.

Comment: @Tomalak you are absolutely right. Old was definitely not the right word; that didn't accurately convey my take on the issue. My personal opinion is that I shouldn't have to accomodate for old browsers OR users using something like a netbook or chromebook that is going to present them with a resolution far lower (<=1024px) than what other comparable, current devices can offer (standard low budget laptops@1366x768 for example). Real world, of course you have to accommodate them, they are a large chunk of your audience, but my personal opinion is that I don't want to.

Comment: And that I support a decision which does not accommodate those users, even if, as you say, the "benefit" of the width increase is trivial or negligible.

Comment: @chiliNUT You are still missing my point. This whole post is not about "supporting out-of-date technology". We are not talking about "phasing out something old in favor of something new" here. I seriously doubt that there was a conscious decision behind that change. There is no indication that the new layout makes any use of the added space. There is no "benefit" at all. And you with your wide screen (or I at my desk) *don't even notice* the change. Ergo: There is no point in keeping it if it inconveniences a share of your users. It's simple logic, really.

Comment: Completely valid points. It is most likely an oversight by the design crew. My personal opinion is that I dont care to correct it for those users, but my professional opinion is that you are correct, there is no reason to inconvenience users for a change that yields no benefit to the rest of the users and was most likely an accident. Agree to disagree?

Comment: @chiliNUT Agree to agree, actually (now that you've given your professional opinion). *Of course* your personal opinion is "works on my machine". ;)

Answer (score 53):

I understand the argument is that the minimum page width is for consistency at the network, but I think there's a strong case to be made here for Stack Overflow as a mild exception to this rule, supported by [dynamic CSS media queries for width](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en).

Stack Overflow is by *farrrrr* the largest Stack Exchange site. It's **larger than every other Stack Exchange site combined together**. I mean, see for yourself:

[image]

If we can't make minor little concessions for The Sun, why not? Without it, the rest of the galaxy would have trouble existing.

Second, Stack Overflow has a very, very large audience established over the last five years -- **it is approaching Wikipedia levels of relevance to the world**. And like Wikipedia, it should make a bit more effort to reach people even in developing countries, even if they don't have the largest screens or best CPUs or what have you.

Plus we used to support 1024px min; if for no other reason than the current design *does* work at that size with a few lines of CSS (see Tomalak's answer here), we ought to continue to support it.

Anyway all I'm proposing is some SO-specific CSS media queries based on width that tighten things up in the current design to fit into 1024px for the users that need it and *only* on Stack Overflow. The rest of the design can stay as is on the rest of the network.

Comment: Welcome back, Jeff. We haven't heard you in a while.

Comment: If we take the Sun from the "100–400 billion stars"* , I doubt the galaxy will notice much :)
-- 
*according to wikipedia

Comment: Thanks Jeff. My thoughts exactly, and a pretty useful compromise suggestion, too. I think 1024px is one of those "notches" in the web design world, it simply doesn't make a lot of sense to miss it by 20px - especially when there is room to spare in mid-page. For the time being I'll add the media query to my UserStyles submission.

Comment: There wouldn't be a 1024 conundrum if SO would lighten up on the amount of whitespace it's killing. In the past year I've seen everything but the padding shrink.

Comment: -1: No freehand _red_ circles (over two years late, too!)

Comment: @Jeff, any chance that SO will ever support wider screens and expand reponsively?
I (and another zillion people) have a wide screen, and I think it's a shame we can't benefit of it having to look at narrow code snippets having to use the horizontal scrollbars always, when this could be avoided.

Comment: Please check out [my post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355548/please-make-post-width-responsive).

Comment: 2018 already - now it's gone up to 1060px! Why can't they remove the padding like other users suggested?

Answer (score 22):

FWIW, there are browser extensions to run your own stylesheets on top of websites (Stylish comes to mind), so I hacked up a CSS override that makes the new design fit into 1024px.

Grab it here: https://userstyles.org/styles/109457/stackoverflow-1024px-screen-fix

```css
@-moz-document regexp("^https?:\\/\\/(meta\\.)?stackoverflow.com\\/.*") {
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
        html, body {
            min-width: 0px;
        }
        #header, #content, .topbar .topbar-wrapper {
            width: 975px;
        }
        .footerwrap {
            width: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        #sidebar, .sidebar {
            width: 210px;
        }
        #ad502-rooms {
            width: 210px;
        }
    }
}
```

The modified layout is 1007px wide and does not trigger a horizontal scrollbar on Chrome and does not look too crammed either.

[image: modified 1024px layout]

Ping me if you notice problems or want to suggest improvements and I'll update my submission to userstyles.org.

Comment: It shouldn't be down to the user to fix styling issues.

Comment: @James Well, it's the pragmatic approach. It solves the issue for me.

Comment: For `.user-show-new .user-panel` add `width: 470px` and for `.user-show-new .user-header .user-about-me` add `width: 440px`. Check your user page to see the fixes.

Comment: @Braiam That's added.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why this site can't be made reactive. I have vertical screens so I'm biased, but I feel ALL websites should be able to at least accommodate 1024 width - according to [statcounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-ww-monthly-201305-201404) at least 20% of screens worldwide have a width at or below 1024px. And what if someone wants to view SO at half-screen-width side-by-side with some other window?

Surely SO can pull one or two engineers that know how to use CSS, right? SO does *not* have a complex layout and it should be easy to make a layout that works for all screen sizes. Honestly, in my opinion, this kind of change is pure laziness.

Answer (score -19):

The reason why we widened the site width and added padding is because:

1. Going on forward and retroactively, we'll make all SE sites' width and padding consistent. So it doesn't matter if a site is one or [two](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) colored background, the dimension and padding should work without additional css tweaks per site. This way, the actual content box would have the same width. In the past, we've had a lot of layout bugs where when we introduced new features due to width inconsistency. This didn't happen on SO too much because being an one-colored-background site, it hid a lot of ugly underneath the hood.
2. But why 1030px? Currently, the left content area's minimum width is 728px, and side bar is 220px. So that's a minimum of 948px without padding and gutter space. In the new design, we wanted some more space between the main area and right side bar. There are some new site features we're working on that require a bit wider area than the old 980px width. We decided 1030px was the best for what we intend to do.

Our traffic data shows the 1024px usage is very very low. So we treat it the same way we treat some of the outdated browser support: it shouldn't be broken, but we're not going to make it pixel perfect.

Comment: I appreciate that there was a thought process behind the chosen width. But *"we made it a tiny bit too wide so we can have more space between the content and the side bar"*? I mean,  seriously? The added benefit in a big screen is zero, the site locks and feels absolutely the same. I would not say anything if SO was an actual wide-screen layout. But it isn't. As it stands, this change does nothing for most users and breaks something for some of them.

Comment: @Tomalak there were other reasons listed above. This change isn't just about SO.

Comment: I'm curious if on point #2 you were looking at viewport sizes or screen resolutions.  If screen resolutions, the methodology is flawed.  As mentioned above in comments, not everyone browses with a full screen browser.

Comment: I suggest a simple responsive design change that does a media query for that particular width and **reduces the size of the gutter between the sidebar and the main page  for ~1024px width to make it fit** -- at least on SO only. This definitely affects me.

Comment: Here's my marked up version. I think that gutter width would be easy to make a few-line conditional CSS query. http://i.imgur.com/wiqQ2yl.png

Comment: @Jin, any chance to have SO shrink and expand its width according to the user screen? I have a wide screen and find it frustrating that the SO website is centered in the middle. All those wide code-snippets requiring you to use the horizontal scrollbar down the page is annoying when my screen easily has room for all that.

Comment: @JeffAtwood responsive design yes! But also the other way, meaning it should expand (at least in SO which is code-based), to take up the entire available screen size.

Comment: Please check out [my post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355548/please-make-post-width-responsive).