# Hidden buttons in half-maximized windows

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I work on a rather standard monitor (1920x1200), and I believe it is usual for programmers and other power users to show multiple windows at once on their screen.

Yet the stackoverflow site is kind of broken when in a window that is maximized to half screen. It forces the user to change the window size, or horizontally scroll, in order to access e.g. the "Ask Question" button:
[image]

In this time of reactive design, I think it isn't wrong to expect such a technically high profile site to be usable in 960x1200?

Comment: related, probably not a dupe because made it an FR: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283703/578411 still expect status-bydesign.

Comment: I have multiple windows open at once - *when I use two screens*. Never felt the need to use a half width window on a normal screen. Anyway, it's possible to do - use the mobile version.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think the half height was just a courtesy on the OP's part so the screen shot doesn't take up too much space

Comment: @Pekka웃: Yea, I figured as much the moment I commented.

Comment: @Pekka: correct. It is the width I question, and my screenshot shows 960 pix width. Also, I have two screens at 1920x1200 each, and still half-maximize windows.

Comment: OP: SO shouldn't go switching around layouts based on arbitrary resolutions. The mobile view @Pekka웃 could be an option.

Comment: @Cerbrus: agreed, maybe. But I wonder how arbitrary "half of 1920x1200" is, especially in the programmer crowd.

Comment: Considering the wide range of screen resolutions available, I don't think it's a good idea. For example, maybe 50% of the users are on that resolution, but that still leaves 50% that aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow has a mobile version that you can use in this kind of situation. It cuts away the sidebar, leaving only questions, answers and the essential buttons.

Click "mobile" in the page footer, you'll probably be able to make it even smaller than half width:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around is to zoom out. At 90 % zoom level, the site is kind of ok at 960x1200.