# The Stack Exchange menu is partly covered by the scrollbar when the window is too narrow

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

This keeps happening if I widen the window, up until the search bar reaches its maximum width and switches to a static width. At that point, the problem quite abruptly goes away:

[image]

It was seen on Firefox 52, Windows 10.

Comment: FWIW, even in environments which auto-hide scrollbars when not in use, that icon looks uncomfortably close to the edge of the screen compared to the spacing between icons at that window size, and the transition point is an obvious jump.

Comment: This really needs more visibility - if they are so set on a sticky top bar, it needs to be able to handle smaller screens (or the browser displaying on half of a screen, as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345814/feature-request-better-layout-at-low-widths?cb=1#345814), without making navigation *impossible* or it's just plain broken.

Answer (score 12):

Not only the menu, but **also the content**.

> asked x
>
> viewed y times

⬑ Notice how these are hidden too and you are forced to scroll horizontally.

Some time ago the website content was increased to `~1100px` from `~900px` *([related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283703/new-page-layout-too-wide-for-1024px); can't seem to find the original post)*, even though it seems it hasn't been made much responsive other than showing / hiding some parts of the navbar (such as the reputation) and making an exclusive mobile site.

### The bug

The worst part of it, which you are probably referring to, is the fact that you can't even scroll to the menu — content scrolls but header keeps on the same position.

Whilst it works fine on tablets:

[image]

On the computer only the content moves.

[image]

However, it only fails on the **computer** when using the fixed header. The **non-sticky header can be scrolled just fine.**

It works fine for tablets, sticky header can be horizontally scrolled.