# Better layout at low widths

Tags: feature-request, design

In short, when I snap SO to the side of my screen 'cos I got another window open beside it, SO is really bad at resizing to accommodate.  Can you make the minimum width of the main content area smaller to better accommodate devs on smaller, single screens without the luxury of size to work with?  According to the Chrome dev console, the window I'm using SO in now is 650px wide.  It's really annoying trying to read and write answers when the content area is wider than the window.

Comment: You can switch to the mobile layout by clicking the *mobile* link in the footer.

Comment: @Stijn Yes, that is a possibility, but the fact is this screen size is _not_ mobile.  Also, having to manually flick a switch to change between modes when going between snapped screen and full screen also isn't desirable.

Comment: 1024x768 was more common than 800x600 almost 15 years ago. I'd absolutely say your window size is to be categorised under *mobile* by today's standards.

Comment: @Stijn The point here isn't that they have a tiny screen, but that they're not using the entire screen for the window.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344521/request-for-redesign-to-have-better-compatibility-with-1024px-wide-displays?rq=1 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345590/the-stack-exchange-menu-is-partly-covered-by-the-scrollbar-when-the-window-is-to/345629#345629

Comment: The screen itself is well over twice that size physically and about twice that CSS width (this is a Surface Pro 4).  It is common practice nowadays to snap two windows beside each other, such as a command line and a text editor, or in this case a browser window with SO and a text editor, especially since all good OSs make this such a simple action.  I believe it is a common enough use case to snap a window to the side of a screen with a resulting *CSS* width of <700px.

Comment: If SO wants to make the life of developers easier, this one should be thought about. I'm often working with my laptop at a customer site where I don't have any screens other than the laptop built-in.

Comment: While I think this might be a beneficial change as well, it seems like there's a good work around in terms of having a user defined style sheet as suggested in @rene's linked questions...

Comment: The layout down't even fit into 1060px properly. So not even on a 1960x1050px monitor when using only half the screen.

Comment: @DanField While that's a reasonable work-around for the hard-core user who can a) be bothered signing up for an account at all and b) realise you can have a custom style sheet, I'd bet a lot of money that over 95% of SO users aren't hard-core users able to do that. Having good default behaviour is essential. Atwood himself praised the value of good defaults: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-power-of-defaults/

Comment: Yeahhh those programmers might not know how to program... I'm just suggesting that with multiple features to consider and finite resources to implement them, this might come out as more of a nice to have than a need to have - and there's a workaround.  I agree that it's a good idea though.

Comment: @DanField Not all devs are web devs. Even for the web devs, I know many who would rather not mess with CSS too much. And from the set of devs who are willing to mess, they have to have time and willpower to custom-implement the CSS on SO. Plus an account. Plus knowledge that SO allows CSS messing (I didn't know before yesterday). Most, actually all of the devs I know IRL apart from myself use SO but don't have accounts, let alone the care to roll their own usability tweak that should have come standard. I mean, responsive layout is a fairly standard UX feature nowadays.

Comment: @Imamadmad Not to take away from your point, but just FYI, all web sites "allow CSS messing". In fact, there's nothing a site can do to stop you from messing with the CSS after it's been loaded into your browser.

Comment: In my experience, this has actually gotten better recently.  I ranted and raved a few months ago when layout changes prevented the entire content area from fitting in half the width of a 1920x1200 monitor with the text at 125%.  But now it does fit.  Even the top-bar fits (well, it fits on most of the SE sites and _almost_ fits on SO--the Documentation Beta is pushing us over the limit there).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan While that is true that all pages can be messed with in the console, preserving changes between page refreshes isn't quite as simple.  I'm sure it is fairly simple with the right know-how, but again, the vast majority of devs don't care enough about web UI to know about and have the necessary tools to save style sheet edits and have them persist between page loads

Comment: It is indicative of the shaky "design" that right now 25% of my frozen meta bar is taken up by the search icon, with my userid & badges excised, while *clicking* on it *resizes* it (which moves the cursor, itself bad but) meaning there is *no point* in having it be so large. Meanwhile my scrolling so bar while also similarly pointlessly compressed is truncated on the right.

Comment: So if there's a mobile link at the footer where it strips the page down and kinda looks like a Bootstrap product, why isn't SO using Bootstrap? I think I read somewhere that responsive design has been rejected but that to me doesn't make sense if you're going to have a dedicated mobile layout anyway.

Comment: @Imamadmad @.Servy Why is the physical screen size even relevant?  Neither CSS nor JavaScript has any mechanism to know your full screen size.  All it knows is the window/document size.  But yeah, I agree with the sentiment of others here— CSS media queries are the standard way to switch which CSS is used based on document size.  Auto-switching to the mobile theme on width < 1075px (the current min) seems an easy & obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to this. On a tablet in portrait mode the layout is just bad and squeezed. All that mostly useless stuff on the right should hide.

[image]