# Did font, spacing, etc. change on stackexchange? [January 2015]

Tags: discussion, bug

Yesterday I've written a question. I've tried to craft the body text in such a way that a paragraph would never be longer than 3 lines if possible, but also include everything. I thought I've achieved that...

However, today I see a 2-line paragraph of mine became a 3-line paragraph and in a similar way a 3-long became a 4-line. To make a point, ***it broke their readability***.

It was very comfortable for me to rely on stackexchange's constant-looking "page width" which seemed to remain constant for a long time now. I wonder, did it just change, just a few pixels?

What to expect?

Comment: I gotta say, the new fonts and layout and just *wrong*!  (But then I'm just a cranky old man who hates change.)

Comment: hm, the other question is several months old... well, the design update *did* break the readability of some writings, well, like mine, obviously...

Comment: I find the entire much site harder to read causing me eye strain and making me sit closer to the monitors.

Comment: How is a question asking about changes that occurred overnight a "duplicate" of a question from two months ago???

Comment: ...should this be tagged as a *bug*?

Comment: @HotLicks the question from 2 months ago announced this new theme with a preview on MSO, so they are at the very least related.

Comment: It seems [setting the font-size back from `15px` to `107%` or `13.7px` would fix this line/paragraph bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283721/611007).

Comment: @KevinVoorn - But any comments placed on that thread will go to the bottom and be ignored.  It's as if they intended to ignore how the users feel about this.