# What was the font's name on Stack Overflow answer body the day before yesterday? [2015 January]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

The new font changed some of my posts lines/paragraph from 3 to 4 which [broke](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283721/611007) their [readability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283714/did-font-spacing-etc-change-on-stackexchange-january-2015#comment143436_283714).

I'm planning to be able to force a custom font from the client-side if I need a quick-fix of readability.

**What was the name of the font Stack Overflow was using just the other day before?**

Comment: Depends on your OS.  It used to map to Arial on my Windows machine.  The font that every designer must love to hate.

Comment: hm, an archive says `Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif`. some random other settings `word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 107%; width: 660px;` `line-height: 130%; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: left;` `margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;`

Comment: it seems the 107% font-size resulted in `13.7px` for me in previously...

Comment: It would be wonderful if you made an extension to rollback some parts of the design, like bold question titles and the font!

Answer (score 1):

It was set in `font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;` at `font-size: 14px`

Comment: thanks! could you perhaps reference how do you know these information? my information is from an archived page.

Comment: I suspect Jin would know this because he was the one that 'broke' it :P  (He works on the design team for Stack Exchange)