# Stack Overflow redesign: visual problems in Firefox 34

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox

The below is visible seen with Firefox 34 ([Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr)). In [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) it's not as visible, or not visible at all. I didn't test it on Firefox under Windows yet. Somehow the old design did not have all these quirks under the very same settings.

#### Digits not aligned in vote count

[image: Look at these 75]

Digits in question / answer vote count also look a little bit shifted towards the bottom:

[image: Look at these 75]

#### Text on buttons is not vertically balanced as is used to be

New Stack Overflow:

[image: Buttons on Stack Overflow]

A nicer design from *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*:

[image: Buttons on Super User]

#### Bounty badge is not aligned to text

[image: Buttons on Stack Overflow]

Compare to a more proper alignment on *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)*:

[image: Buttons on Unix & Linux]

---

I started a new thread because [the old one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/) has overflowed.

Comment: Today Firefox is 35 in Ubuntu 14.04 and I see things right.

Comment: @DavidJacquel: Indeed, in FF 35 things look much better! The only thing I still feel odd about is alignment of bounty plaques. They are also shifted up in Chrome, so it might be not a Firefox-specific regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm marking this status-completed because the only remaining bug after Firefox fixed their issues in 34 (with 35) is bounties. These will be aligned properly in the next build.