# Can we get a better font for Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

(EDIT): It appears this issue only exists for people who see [Helvetica Neue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica#Neue_Helvetica_.281983.29), and Windows users do not by default see Helvetica Neue.

In the request for feedback for the new Stack Overflow theme [I posted a specific problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/277558#277558) that I see: that Helvetica Neue, while it looks very neat and professional on one hand, has poor readability, especially in the case of trying to distinguish between lower-case i and l. I was somewhat late to the party as far as feedback, but it still got some upvotes.

I always hated fonts that basically conflate uppercase I's and lower case l's, but that was only a problem when George Bush called Kim Jong Il Kim Jong the Second in a speech (they should've known to use a serif font for printed text!). But this problem goes way beyond that.

In case this renders differently for some people I'll post some pictures of what I'm seeing (ripped from my old post):

Helvetica Neue Screenshot 1: [image: Chrome Helvetica Neue Screenshot 1]

Helvetica Neue Screenshot 2: [image: Chrome Helvetica Neue Screenshot 2]

Zoomed in:

[image: Chrome Screenshot Enlarged]

Even zoomed in I can barely find space between that i and its dot.

Here's a word that is difficult to read in this font (other than the word difficult): illegitimate

Is that word supposed to have six l's in it? No. Did I just type six l's or six i's. Can you tell?

I understand that your designers do not want to design by democracy, and there are aspects of the new style I can learn to live with, but this particular issue is one I'd like to see addressed.

I literally read every lowercase i as l, and it is terribly distracting, and I figure it has to be for someone else besides me. I also think the bad readability goes beyond i and l: the kerning is "scrunched" (to use a totally official word for it) <s>and it looks like all the words are bold. **What does a bold sentence even look like in this font?** Oh, that's what it looks like.</s>

<s>**This sentence is bold.**</s>

This sentence is not bold.

<s>(EDIT) For those not seeing the bold problem like I am, this is what I see on this page, (Chrome for Windows 7, 39.0.2171.99):</s>

Chrome bold picture:

(EDIT 2): The comments and answer were spot-on. Judging from comments and other upvotes in the other thread this i and l issue may exist for Macs, but there was no bold issue (gah).

Comment: I agree with everything except the bold. On Chrome, 100% zoom, the bold difference is very clear.

Comment: Hmm I'm also on Chrome 100%, and I can't see a difference? Maybe that part's just me for some reason. (I've added a picture)

Comment: Your machine is borken.  Try superuser.com

Comment: Running the exact same (Chrome, same version, Windows 7) and I don't see a single issue that you're mentioning. You're example word, illegitimate, looks perfectly fine to me. Check your browser's font settings to ensure you (or another user) haven't done anything weird to it.

Comment: No-repro on my end, Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 m @ Windows 7. I don't think it's an SO issue. Something may be potato with your Chrome.

Comment: That being said, of course, that font is ATROCIOUS. Even Comic Sans would be a better choice. *puts on flame suit*

Comment: I can't stand the new format.  I am an old fart, and need my big, ugly fonts back!

Comment: gimme verdana :<

Comment: I installed [StylesTuner](http://download.serienjunkies.org/f-860bd9de3a31c8e0/ul_helixWEBHD106.html) in my Firefox to change the appearance of sites I don't like. Works for the Font in SO as well.

Comment: We are trying to repro this but cannot - I can't understand from the question if you're on Windows with the font installed or...? Can you please post OS, Browser, and any non-default details with fonts on your system so that we can try to repro again?

Comment: My first comment on the accepted answer explains (rather poorly, my apologies) that I had installed Helvetica Neue on my Win7 machine years ago. That's why I was seeing this font. On top of that I'm not sure my screenshots are of Helvetica Neue Medium, they are most likely from Helvetica Neue bold. But people on Macs continue to upvote and post about this being a problem. I don't have a Mac to test on, but I think non-bold HN is better than my screenshots - still, people who see a change on Mac seem to dislike the readability vs. Arial. My apologies again for this being a mess of a question.

Comment: As I said in a comment on an answer (you can read here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283788/can-we-get-a-better-font-for-stack-overflow-questions?cb=1#comment144731_283833) you have to enable ClearType. Chrome has this quirk that the font becomes all bold when ClearType is disabled. (Opera 12.xx shows the font as if it was console font, but weirdly scaled. That's another example of the quirks that happen with ClearType disabled.)

Comment: If you are trying to show minute details in screenshots, perhaps .jpg might not be the best image format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we can have a better font—for some values of “better”. Font preferences are largely a matter of taste and also context-dependent.

The current overall setting at SO is `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`. This means that the majority sees Arial, Mac users and some others see some Helvetica, and the others see whatever happens to be the browser’s default sans-serif font. This is fairly common, and that’s the main reason for keeping it. The second reason is that there are few realistic alternatives.

Just setting `font-family: sans-serif` would give everyone the default sans-serif font of his browser, which cannot be that bad.

Removing `font-family` setting entirely would give everyone his preferred font, provided that he has set his browser to use it. This would be the best option if SO were created today. Visitors can be expected to be knowledgeable enough to set the font, at least if encouraged and instructed to. However, changing the font settings of an existing, high-volume site is something completely different. Besides, if we think that users, rather than site management, should set font family, we should think the same about font sizes (and set font sizes only relatively).

As I don’t think that’s realistic, the question is whether there are other feasible options.

What you seem to have as a problem is specific to your situation. In a normal Windows 7 system, there is no Helvetica Neue or Helvetica (unless separately installed). Windows peculiarly maps Helvetica to Arial when no font named Helvetica is present, so almost all Windows 7 users see the text in Arial. In Arial, regular and bold typeface is visibly different. So you probably have either browser settings that override fonts set at SO pages or a font named Helvetica Neue or Helvetica, possibly somehow broken (e.g. so that regular typeface is used instead of bold typeface).

Comment: I had assumed Helvetica Neue came with Windows 7, thank you for clearing that up.  I've gone through dev fonts on our old svn that was used for graphics and it was one of the ones installed to deal with old company brochures. I haven't dealt with the brochures in years. NOW I FEEL LIKE A REAL WINNER :( Should have waited until I got home, that computer's a fresh install. That said the old post of mine had upvotes and some people seem to agree here, so perhaps Mac users are having this problem while the rest of us enjoy Arial's qualities of comfortable meh? My thanks to you and commentors.

Comment: What was the setting for the old (readable) SO? Yes I am on a Mac

Comment: The font on superuser is: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif; I believe I remember seeing Liberation Sans when I was looking through it before, but not DejaVu. I'd guess you saw Arial (included with OS X according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X ) rather than Helvetica Neue. I'd think users would all prefer to see the same font if possible, so maybe Arial could be placed first on the list.

Comment: How is only using relative font sizes infeasible?  *Not* using relative font sizes is a UX sin.

Comment: There are plenty of ways of making sure everyone is seeing the same font, I don't understand this dark ages mentality. [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)? [Font Face](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)? On my systems I use the Ubuntu font on Google and have a Font Face backup (which can be downloaded [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?q%5Bterm%5D=ubuntu&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y))

Comment: @JamieBarker, the question was not about making everyone see the same font but about getting a better font..

Comment: My comment was not in response to the question, it was a response to paragraph 2 of your answer. In particular to the last sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [Linux Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) and can confirm that there is a strange font - only on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow, all other Stack Exchange sites looks OK. I checked that I don't have all of those fonts - `Helvetica Neue`, `Helvetica` and `Arial` are all not installed on my system. The default font is `Liberation Serif`, and I would be fine with it, but Firefox shows me some other unreadable font; I have no idea which. Looking at what [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) has I found that they specify other fonts that are installed on my system and are much better readable:

```css
font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
```

After experimenting a bit around I found out that `Helvetica` seems to have a font that is displayed instead of it that isn't good readable. Can we maybe get settings like this:

```css
body {
  font-family: Liberation Sans, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
}
.old {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a test to demonstrate the readability of the font.</p>
<p class="old">This is a test to demonstrate the readability of the font.</p>
```

As you can see it looks much better than the old one on my system:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Are you saying Helvetica is being used on your system, as in some version of it is installed? That *shouldn't* be the case unless you've installed it from somewhere (which generally doesn't work well outside a mac OS). Can you clarify what's happening a bit? We'll certainly take a look!

Comment: @NickCraver No, I don't have Helvetica, but when I specify to use Helvetica in CSS before any other installed font this poorly readable font is displayed; I have no idea what happens here. I tested with LibreOffice and it used the default font after I set it to Helvetica manually. It seems like FF is using some font instead of Helvetica, but I never told him so and it doesn't shows that in the settings as well.

Comment: Oh yeah, please use the proposed font-family. Everything is bold-ish for me right now, and I'm having a harder time reading stuff than ever before.

Comment: @stefan If you are on Windows, enable ClearType. That's a problem when people disable ClearType. Chrome shows it all bold.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That's not the issue, because I have ClearType enabled.

Comment: @stefan I've seen some issues where you enable ClearType but it doesn't take effect. Did you defined the advanced settings to have no effects at all? Sorry for the English, I'm not being able to express myself correctly. If you go to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/optimize-windows-better-performance#optimize-windows-better-performance=windows-7 and look for "Turn off visual effects", you will understand what I'm trying (and fail) to say.

Comment: @NickCraver Can you please fix this issue quickly? SO is currently really unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Using any form of Helvetica at high level in a font stack will get you angry Linux users.

Because Helvetica is a very old font, and besides part of the mandatory PostScript font set, it is very common to find it in one derivative form or other on Linux systems (via Ghostscript, Tex or something similar). However those are all *old* Helvetica variants, intended for mostly ASCII-only text, in bitmap formats or at best outline formats without hinting (for print not screen media). So a browser *will* find native Helvetica on Linux, but it *will* look bad on screen.

There was an effort to modernise the Postscript font set on free/open systems (TEX Gyre) but it stumbled at a critical moment by making novice licensing mistakes. Since then Linux integrators have been mostly ignoring it even though the legal problems should be fixed now.

The most common sans serif font on Linux systems should be DejaVu Sans (and DejaVu Sans Mono). The most common Helvetica-ish modern font (but less prevalent, with smaller coverage, and some hinting woes) is Liberation Sans (an Arial substitute, Arial having been described as a botched Helvetica when initially release). And if you're keen on Helvetica, TeX Gyre Heros, which is a clean modern helvetica variant, but few people will have it installed.