# Why does body text all appear bold on macOS in Safari?

Tags: bug, design, safari

This may be related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350039/why-is-everything-bold-now) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283788/can-we-get-a-better-font-for-stack-overflow-questions), but both those are old now.

After I upgraded to macOS Mojave, all body text on all SO sites appears in bold when I browse in Safari 13, for example:

[image: text in Safari]

However, I don't think this is a system font issue because it renders quite differently in Chrome Canary 81, running on the same system with the same fonts available:

[image: text in Chrome]

It's acting exactly like it's really bold, not just a difference in rendering. Safari's font rending is historically different, and generally better, than Chrome's, but I'm pretty sure this isn't that because normal text and intentionally bold text are identical; markup like this

```
not bold **bold**
```

results in

[image]

It is however specific to the font for normal body text; the monospaced font used for code elements (like the editing panel) does not do have this problem.

FWIW, I do have both Helvetica Neue and Arial installed.

Can anyone point me at a specific cause of this, and a possible remedy?

Comment: You're not zoomed in / out, right? Does disabling responsiveness helps? Is it the same if you switch to the mobile view?

Comment: I'm not zoomed, and disabling responsiveness doesn't help, but **mobile view is not bold**! Also it's not a general problem - it's just SO sites, possibly Google spreadsheets too. Perhaps I have a bad Arial font?

Comment: I'm not getting this issue. Mojave, Safari 13.0.1

Comment: If I understand correctly you shouldn't have an Arial font on an Apple OS. `"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica` should be the font that gets selected.

Comment: Having Arial installed on a Mac isn’t the least bit unusual - it would be expected on any Mac that has had Microsoft Office installed on it within the last 20 years or so.

Comment: @rene [Arial is preinstalled on macOs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208968). For the issue at hand, I can't repro on my Safari 13.0.4 on 10.15.2 (both on built-in retina and external non-retina).

Comment: Of course. @rene isn’t saying Arial won’t be installed or available. He’s saying that Helvetica variants will also be available, and those will be used in preference to Arial.

Comment: I haven't used Safari in years, but I seem to remember there being something similar to Developer Tools, where you can alter CSS of elements live. I'd try setting `font-weight: bold` on `html` and see if it gets any bolder. It may be that you have Arial Bold aliased to Arial somehow, or it's mistaking `font-weight: 400` (the defined weight) for bold when using Arial...?

Comment: @Cody I read once again rene's comment and to me what this comment says still means "you shouldn't have an Arial font on an Apple OS.". If you look at the css, it's first Arial then Helvetica, so no reasons Arial wouldn't get picked up if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked my setup in FontBook and found something a little unexpected. Not only is Arial installed by default, but *the system actively prevents you from disabling or removing it* from there!

I then found that I could still remove it from my system fonts folder manually, **and that stopped everything appearing in bold**. I still have a copy of Arial installed, but it's in `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft` along with all the other standard Microsoft fonts (Verdana, Trebuchet, Consolas, Comic Sans, etc).

So, I think this problem was down to a duplicate font that was also corrupted, and it was solved by reverting to the stock Microsoft Arial font instead

Comment: **Missed an opportunity to post this in all-bold.**