# Strange font in reputation counter

Tags: bug, design

I am seeing my reputation displayed in a very curious font family, see the image below:

[image]

Is that intentional?

Firefox Quantum ESR 68.6.1esr
MacOS 10.14.6
Dark Mode on Stack Exchange
Copied and pasted characters: 1,642

Comment: Can you copy and paste the characters? And check with the browser's inspector the actual content for that div?

Comment: This was also on a mac: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392222/578411 maybe it gives a clue if something local on your box got confused.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I restarted the computer, and it's back to normal. I guess there was some temporary corruption. All good now. Thanks!