# duplicate close vote dialogue is too narrow for new column width

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Well, the title says it all:

[image: screenshot of a random close vote dialogue with horizontal scrollbar]

That horizontal scrollbar shouldn't be there. Oh, and it's a wonderful example of how the [vote counts are still misaligned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277207/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after the next production build.