# Cut in the Jon Skeet's profile view

Tags: bug, design

Just came across Jon Skeet's one of answers, where I saw cut in his profile view. His badges are getting cut at 100% zoom but it's clearly visible with 110% zoom level.

**100% Zoom :**

[image]

**110% Zoom :**
[image]

Comment: It's like with close review queue. The purpose here is to hide their real count to keep people motivated. Now seriously, I would *workaround* this by *shortening* those numbers just like score does, to 5k and 6.3k since I doubt someone cares about their exact count in answer post.

Comment: Already reported before it goes live on main site (number 2): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277208/1400768 :P though making a separate question gives it more attention.

Comment: @TLama That will only solve the problem until he inevitably gets to 100k badges.

Comment: @JLRishe, considering the current frequency, it will take him more than 90 years to get 100k bronze badges. Which is quite enough time for possible fix. But someone might be faster (don't have time to research this). In any case, I don't think it's useful to show the exact count.

Comment: It's OK. Jon doesn't need all those bronze badges anyway.

Comment: @TLama: If he reached 100k badges then we can safely round up to ∞ badges. I think, it will take him slightly longer than 90 years to beat that.

Comment: Such is Jon Skeet's power

Comment: why does this matter?