# Stack Overflow-specific features

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Are there any features regarding the Stack Overflow web site that are only specific to it? Or all features are shared (the same) between all Stack Exchange sites?

I am asking this question, because until now I didn't see any specific one (probably because I am a little new here), and I was wondering what kind of Stack Overflow-specific feature-request could we suggest (that aren't present on any other Stack Exchange sites)?

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. Are you talking about Meta vs. SO, or SO vs. the rest of the SE sites?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the rest of SE sites, Is there any specific options or features that exist only in SO?

Comment: It's very likely that there are, although I'm not sure whether there is a list. You should definitely edit out the "Meta" in your post then, no?

Comment: Most things that are SO specific are features that exist on every single site, but that are turned off on non-SO sites.

Comment: Hey, everyone forgot!

After the [redesign](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update), SO is **fully svgifyied** - look at logos, vote buttons, the favoriting star, editor buttons, etc. There are no other fully svgifyied sites in SE network.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. The [Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) is unique to Stack Overflow, due to the volume of questions.
2. Stack Overflow is the only site where it requires at least three users to review a suggested edit, all other sites require only two users

That said, since all sites share the same codebase, it's not technically possible to have site-only feature (e.g. voting or favorites), and it won't make any sense to begin with.

Comment: Both are configuration issues more than anything. I'm sure the Triage queue could be enabled on other sites too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course they can, but can't imagine another website needing it so badly as Stack Overflow. (Triage - no idea about reviews )

Comment: Btw, about triage queue: you can find that http://*.stackexchange.com/review/triage/stats is available on any SE site. But its right that seems only SO needz triage now.

Comment: @nicael pretty much the same as Martjin said above.. infrastructure exists, but not used in other sites.

Comment: Wouldn't support for TeX-style `$...$` mathematics notation on math.SE qualify as a site-specific feature? AFAIK pretty mathematics isn't a general feature.

Comment: @mu not sure what you mean? Anyway might be worth a new answer :)

Comment: You say "it's not technically possible to have site-only feature (e.g. voting or favorites), and it won't make any sense to begin with" but the mathematics sites have markup (e.g.: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/206890/215964) that I don't think is generally available. So there are site-only features and they do make sense.

Comment: @mu I see. But at least [24 sites are using MathJax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/152859) so... :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your awesome clarifications :) Each questions I ask, I end by getting more info than I was expecting

Comment: Triage is not enabled SO-only because of volume; it's enabled SO-only because it's still in testing, and SO is a convenient place to test it. Once it's ironed out, as far as I know, other sites will have it available and at least some will probably start using it.

Comment: @Nathan interesting, where you saw that? Dev/CM said something about it?

Comment: Also Stack Overflow is the only site that is integrated with the Careers site.

Comment: @David while true, it's not really a "feature". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I disagree, and in fact considering it one of the best and most differentiating features. But that gets into the semantics of what is a true feature - not really that important.

Comment: I would think StackSnippets are not enabled on all sites (though it's not specific to SO)

Comment: @Bergi they're enabled on MSE as well, but good point, totally forgot about it!

Comment: Actually, the triage queue would be enabled elsewhere once they figure out how to scale it properly.