# New styling of vote count/bounty award has insufficient padding on fade in

Tags: bug, design

The new styling on vote counts in user profiles is really nice. I quite like it.

It looks like that style has also been applied to bounty awards in existing answers.  When clicking a link from the Achievements list, it takes you to the target answer, which has a brief fading background.  The new styling of a bounty award reaches the edge of the background color's boundary.

It isn't severe, but is a little visually jarring as the color fade happens. You can [see the effect in action with this answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104044/what-is-causing-the-message-failed-loading-usr-lib-php-modules-xdebug-so-no/22152729#22152729)

Here's an image of it mid-fade:

[image: Bounty award at edge of bounding box]

The other place I suspect this would occur is on deleted answers for 10k users. Obviously it's a rare edge case, affecting 10k users viewing *deleted* answers on which a bounty was awarded.

Thanks to [TLama](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) for locating a deleted bounty-awarded answer:

[image: Deleted bounty awarded answer]

Comment: ??? I don't know how I managed to make the image blown up like that. Something weird with ImageMagick I guess.

Comment: Here is a [sample of deleted post with bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388437/960757). The fade effect seems to be same as for any other post.

Comment: See also [this feedback on *Stack Overflow design update*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277207/1048572)

Comment: Looks like [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) fixes this, at least sort of. It's not on purpose, though -- the [bounty styling fix](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5783) currently included in SOUP was written long before the SO design update.