# Too much space between posts on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Everything was fine an hour ago and suddenly I see my profile page as follows. I have tried refreshing and clearing the cache and checking this site's profile page too. It looks the same here too.

Stack Overflow

[image]

MSO

[image]

---

Looking at the CSS both the anchor tag and table data tag have `margin-bottom: 18px`

Comment: Yep, this extra `margin-botton` of `1.2em` is way too big.

Comment: [It's not a bug, it's a feature!](http://www.improgrammer.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/imagesbug_20vs_20feature_small.jpg)

Comment: Yes and it leaves a lot empty space after the tags and badges sections

Comment: @Rizier123 LOL is it new? it wasn't like this in the morning.

Comment: I'm looking into this now and assign blame accordingly.

Comment: @Sri Now you have enough space to write something between the lines! See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277228/3933332 <- As you can see there wasn't enough space for the red text, now there is ;D

Comment: I for one, kind of like it actually. Especially the new boxed numbers.

Comment: NOOOOO! Don't touch it! I like it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: Thanks When will it go live?

Comment: @sri already...

Comment: @Sri should be in the next 2 hours or so.

Comment: @Jin My profile looks normal now.

Comment: @Jin Hey, If you didn't already noticed it, the time in the answer section is a little bit off to the left, see: http://imgur.com/MsnrKEX

Comment: @Rizier123 we're fixing that bug