# Tag badge trackers are taking up too much space in the tracker chooser popup

Tags: discussion, design

In the selector menu for the tag badge tracker, the spacing under the progress bars is unnecessarily large. It suggests that there should be some information sometimes, but, as far as I know, that space is unused.

[image: tag badge tracker menu]

What is the description space used for?

[image: description]

Comment: Is this space causing some kind of an unexpected behaviour, or do you just simply think it does not look nice?

Comment: It's the latter, hence why I put this up as a discussion.

Comment: Do you consider this such a priority issue that needs meta duscussion and implementation by the SO development team?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the main things Meta exists. Consider [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287456/too-much-space-between-posts-on-profile-page) question, it basically remains on the same concept.

Comment: I see that list quite often. I can count on my two hands how many times I accessed the badge tracker selector in almost 2 years.

Comment: @Shadow meta is for discussion and feedback of all level. Not only high priority. Defining the priority happens through our votes and the dev team. That the dev team is busy in designing hats and Tamagotchi®s (and feeding unicorns), shouldn't change how we use meta.

Comment: I added a screenshot to make your post more meaningfull. Feel free to roll back if that is not in your intention