# Who did the design for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, design

Does anyone know who did the design for Stack Overflow? I'm just trying wondering if the developers themselves did it, or if they hired designers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The original [first iteration design](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-beta-design/) was done by [Jeremy Kratz](http://www.jeremykratz.com/), and the original logo was created by [Peter Borlace](http://pbdesignsolutions.com/project/stack-overflow/), and was [picked in a contest](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/). Some other people have helped out too; listen to [podcast #16](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/podcast-16/) for the details.

Stack Exchange has since [hired an in-house designer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/), and Jin Yang has been handling the Stack Overflow design updates ever since (the design was [last refreshed late last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update)). Currently, the design team consists of [4 designers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-58-pack-em-in-like-bees/), unless more people have been added by now.

Comment: The logo could now be considered as "inspired" by Peter Borlace's original design. It's now been redesigned to be less.. curvy.

Comment: SE also hired [a few more designers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-58-pack-em-in-like-bees/): Stéphane Martin, Courtny Cotten, and Josh Hynes.

Comment: @animuson: right, I meant that the original logo design was by him. I'll see about tweaking the sentence.

Comment: On the logo: see http://en.99designs.nl/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774 -- and click the link to the designer! Someone is having regrets.

Comment: @usr2564301 at that page the text under design now reads "Winning design by Please_Remove"