# Is there a good reason why the [META] wordmark on the new header image is now orange and no longer maroon?

Tags: discussion, design, meta

I can't see how this would make meta any less confusing for users who are lost. Not that we can do much to help folks either, but the color change seems completely gratuitous otherwise. The accent color of meta has pretty much always been maroon.

Comment: Because rebranding. Careers and beta got the same consistent shade of orange.

Comment: See the [Russian Stack Overflow logo](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) for example.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: OK, I had no idea it was based on a [BETA] wordmark. Still seems awfully inconsistent with the rest of the meta theme.

Comment: Because meta no longer [means murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/)...

Comment: It's more of a light maiming these days.

Comment: "meta" should be bigger.  And spring loaded.  To shoot out and smack people right in their mugs if they post a programming question.

Comment: You really want to discuss a simple color change? ... (._.  )

Comment: Given the ridiculous number of posts about the texture of the 10mq banner, SE no doubt thinks it is pretty essential to get programmers used to having their cheese moved once in a while.  Embrace Change™, a public service by SE™.

Comment: @edrodriguez: If they saw fit to change it I see no reason not to discuss it.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Excellent point.

Comment: that I did, read too quickly, thanks for pointing it out @Louis

Comment: I like it. It's the same size and shape as the little rep change notification :)

Comment: Relevant blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/?cb=1

Comment: The new careers logo is even more ugly than this.

Comment: @inf Not only that, but where did my cheese go?

Comment: I think it's way too easy to confuse Meta with Beta now.

Comment: [Meta] was maroon? I didn't even know (red-green color deficient guy here)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In that case why the *favicon* on the [Russian Stack Overflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) is blue ?

Comment: @Abhitalks To match the national colours of Russia, I think. The [Portuguese favicon](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) is green.

Comment: @HansPassant They figured the cheese was part of the [bad sandwich that Carmack posted about on Instagram](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). But now developers who can't find their cheese are being failed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The color was changed because orange is Stack Overflow's primary brand color. Maroon red is not the brand's primary color.

[image: Stack Overflow Meta Logo Breakdown]

Comment: The more I sit on this the more I think I understand what you're getting at. The meta flag is intended to reflect the overall branding, much like the beta flag, rather than the meta site design itself. Is that right? (Actually I'm not even sure if what I said makes sense...)

Comment: Your diagram would be better if you actually included the main site logo, too. That, and some red freehand circles.

Comment: Meta flags should reflect the parent community. Since the parent is Stack Overflow in this case, the meta flag is orange. If the parent community's primary color was blue or red, then the meta flag should reflect that.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: @Hynes Since you don't have a diamond here on SO, you could change your nickname from `Hynes` to `Hynes (Product Designer at SO)` so that may clear some confusion if you write answers about the design of SO. *Just an idea*

Comment: Stack Exchange... errr Stack Overflow employees who do not have moderation privileges should have a different insignia.  Maybe a lightbulb.  Changing the name would add nothing but confusion, because you then have to ask whether it's the real deal or a copycat.  Site-integrated flair doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @Rizier123 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161197/216712

Comment: There are other reserved Unicode characters which could serve the purpose, e.g. the empty diamond.

Comment: "was changed because orange" , ...... >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283819/3041194 <<<<<<<<<